# regular expression to limit 300 words

Tags: java, regex, exception, stack-overflow

I need a regex which success 0-300 words and fails 301 or more words.

I tried:

```
^\s*(\S+\s+){0,300}\S*$
```

I also checked

```
^\W*(?:\w+\b\W*){0,300}$
```

Both are working fine but in Java I get a *java.lang.StackOverflowError*. I know using a larger "XSS" I get around this issue but I wanted to ask if there is a way to optimize the regex?

Comment: *"Both are working fine but in Java I get a "java.lang.StackOverflowError""* Um, how can they be "working fine" **and** be throwing an exception?

Comment: Sorry you're right... Both are doing the job fine if I test the in an online regex tool such as https://regex101.com/ but in Java they are not working

Comment: Then you'll need to show your code using it, as that's likely to be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is because the Java implementation of Pattern uses up a stack for each repetition of a group because of backtracking. The solution might be to either change your approach as others have answered or to make all quantifiers possessive :

```
^\s*(\S+\s+){0,300}+\S*$
```

or

```
^\W*(?:\w+\b\W*){0,300}+$
```

For more info, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509905/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-while-using-a-regex-to-parse-big-strings) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21704371/1514241).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.split` and check the size of the returned array.

Comment: I can't, I'm using a constraint framework. And it would really be complicated to write own code (maybe very last resort). Any idea if the regex can be improved?

Comment: `String.split` is part of standard Java - what do you mean?

Comment: I'm using hibernate constraint, I can't add custom Java code. Only regex changes...

Comment: should have maybe mentioned that in your question and tagged it appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will fail if the `300th` word is the last word and there is not`space` ahead of it.You should use

```
^ *(?:\S+(?: +|$)){0,300} *$
```