# Using String Split

Tags: c#, .net

I have a text

Category2,"Something with ,comma"

when I split this by ',' it should give me two string

- Category2
- "Something with ,comma"

but in actual it split string from every comma.

how can I achieve my expected result.

Thanx

Comment: Break down your problem into a simple set of rules. What do you want to do? Are you saying you want to split on a comma, but *not* if it is enclosed in double quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `variable.Split(new char[] { ',' }, 2)`. Complete documentation in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx).

Comment: Hi thanx, as the solution shows it separate the string from first ',' it works for me, but suppose there is a string My, Name ,Is BreakHead. and it should split like this My, Name and Is BreakHead ?

Comment: General solution depends on your data and what it can contain. Check other answers provided to your question, they also provide nice solutions.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things that you could be wanting to do here so I will address a few:

Split on the first comma

```
String text = text.Split(new char[] { ',' }, 2);
```

Split on every comma

```
String text = text.Split(new char[] {','});
```

Split on a comma not in `"`

```
var result = Regex.Split(samplestring, ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)");
```

Last one taken from [C# Regex Split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147836/c-regex-split-commas-outside-quotes)

Comment: Your last example works for strings inside ' not inside ". You would have to to this as : `Regex.Split(text, ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")` if the string is within ", as in the example of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the maximum number of strings you want in the array:

```
string[] parts = text.Split(new char[] { ',' }, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Split` works at the simplest, fastest level - so it splits the text on all of the delimiters you pass into it, and it has no concept of special rules like double-quotes.

If you need a CSV parser which understands double-quotes, then you can write your own or there are some excellent open source parsers available - e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx - this is one I've used in several projects and recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitToSubstrings(this string str)
    {
        int startIndex = 0;
        bool isInQuotes = false;

        for (int index = 0; index < str.Length; index++ )
        {
            if (str[index] == '\"')
                isInQuotes = !isInQuotes;

            bool isStartOfNewSubstring = (!isInQuotes && str[index] == ',');                

            if (isStartOfNewSubstring)
            {
                yield return str.Substring(startIndex, index - startIndex).Trim();
                startIndex = index + 1;
            }
        }

        yield return str.Substring(startIndex).Trim();
    }
}
```

Usage is pretty simple:

```
foreach(var str in text.SplitToSubstrings())
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```