# Split NSString preserving quoted substrings

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, split, quotes

I need to split up a string which is separated by commas while preserving any quoted substrings (which may have commas too).

String example:

```
NSString *str = @"One,Two,\"This is part three, I think\",Four";
for (id item in [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","])
    NSLog(@"%@", item);
```

This returns:

- One
- Two
- "This is part three
- I think"
- Four

The correct result (respecting quoted substrings) should be:

- One
- Two
- "This is part three, I think"
- Four

Is there a reasonable way to do this, without re-inventing or re-writing quote-aware parsing routines?

Comment: Regular Expressions http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's think about this a different way.  What you have is a comma-seperated string, and you want the fields in the string.

There's some code for that:

https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

And you'd do this:

```
NSString *str = @"One,Two,\"This is part three, I think\",Four";
NSArray *lines = [str CSVComponents];
for (NSArray *line in lines) {
  for (NSString *field in line) {
    NSLog(@"field: %@", field);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C# answer to the same problem.

[C# Regex Split - commas outside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3147836/402706)

You could probably use the same Regex in Objective-C

[NSString split Regex](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~weinrich/projects/fscript/StringRegex/Categories/NSString_StringRegex_/CompositePage.html#//apple_ref/doc/compositePage/occ/instm/NSString%28StringRegex%29/split:) with `,(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)`