# Question about ,(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)

Tags: c#, regex

[C# Regex Split - commas outside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147836/c-regex-split-commas-outside-quotes)

```
var result = Regex.Split(samplestring, ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*')*[^\"]*$)");
```

I have problems to understand how it works.

Specifically, I don't know what the * matches here?

```
",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")
                     ^
```

Does it mean

there are 0 or more of `(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*')`

**update for a sample input**

```
2,1016,7/31/2008 14:22,Geoff Dalgas,6/5/2011 22:21,http://stackoverflow.com,"Corvallis, OR",7679,351,81,b437f461b3fd27387c5d8ab47a293d35,34
```

Use the following code to test:

```
string samplestring = "2,1016,7/31/2008 14:22,Geoff Dalgas,6/5/2011 22:21,http://stackoverflow.com,\"Corvallis, OR\",7679,351,81,b437f461b3fd27387c5d8ab47a293d35,34";
```

Comment: Your sample data has double-quotes and your regex matches single-quotes. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the group `(?:[^']*'[^']*')` is matched zero or more times.

```
,       // match one comma
(?=     // Start a positive lookAHEAD assertion
(?:     // Start a non-capturing group
[^']*   // Match everything but a single-quote zero or more times
'       // Match one single-quote
[^']*   // Match everything but a single-quote zero or more times
'       // Match one single-quote
)*      // End group and match it zero or more times
[^']*   // Match everything but a single-quote zero or more times
$)      // end lookAHEAD
```

Comment: @Greg, based on your comments, why the following doesn't work ",(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)")
why we have to use a passive group?

Comment: @q0987 - What is your input? I ran some quick tests and it seemed to work the same as both a passive group and a regular group.

Comment: @Greg, I have added a sample data row. It only works for me if we use a passive group

Comment: @q0987 - I used http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test against your sample data. Both capturing and passive groups had the same result. Maybe .NET treats them differently than flash. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You could check your regex and make your test on this website :

http://www.annuaire-info.com/outil-referencement/expression-reguliere/

;) have fun