# Use RegEx to select SN from text string

Tags: regex

Hi I'm new in Regular expression.
Please kindly help me to use regex to select SN from text string.
I have

```
Agilent Technologies,86100D,MY53060185,A.10.80
```

My purpose is to select "MY53060185", 
I try to using look behind for "," character 
with this regex

```
(?<![a-z A-Z0-9])(?<!,)(?<![a-z A-Z0-9])(?<!,)[a-z A-Z0-9]+
```

So far failed.

I would be appreciated if you can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which language you're using?

Comment: your first attempt uses grouping. do you need to retain all these groups?

Comment: Loose, but [this](https://regex101.com/r/zU3hD7/1) and/or [this](https://regex101.com/r/zU3hD7/2) might help you.

Comment: it kinda looks like one line of a CSV file so you could try and use a CSV parser to get what you need (if you use C# have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147836/c-sharp-regex-split-commas-outside-quotes/3148691#3148691

Comment: I want to use this regex in C#.

Comment: I forgot about split string, Thanks pastacool

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the lookarounds and use capturing group and start of the line anchor..

```
^[a-z A-Z0-9]+,[a-z A-Z0-9]+,([a-z A-Z0-9]+)
```

Now get the string you want from group index 1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your SN **ALWAYS** starts with `MY` followed by numbers, the following simple regex will capture it:

`/(MY\d+)/`

If this is not what you want or doesn't work with a specific scenario, let me know and I can moddify it to accompany any other situation you may have. Hope that helps!