# Catching a pattern, but ignoring it within quotes

Tags: c#, regex

So, what I need to do in c# regex is basically split a string whenever I find a certain pattern, but ignore that pattern if it is surrounded by double quotes in the string.

Example:

```
string text = "abc , def , a\" , \"d , oioi";
string pattern = "[ \t]*,[ \t]*";

string[] result = Regex.Split(text, pattern, RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

Wanted **result** after split (3 splits, 4 strings):

```
    {"abc",
     "def",
     "a\" , \"d",
     "oioi"}
```

Actual **result** (4 splits, 5 strings):

```
    {"abc",
     "def",
     "a\"",
     "\"d",
     "oioi"}
```

Another example:

```
string text = "a%2% 6y % \"ad%t6%&\" %(7y) %";
string pattern = "%";

string[] result = Regex.Split(text, pattern, RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

Wanted **result** after split (5 splits, 6 strings):

```
    {"a",
     "2",
     " 6y ",
     " \"ad%t6%&\" ",
     "(7y) ",
     ""}
```

Actual **result** (7 splits, 8 strings):

```
    {"a",
     "2",
     " 6y ",
     "\"ad",
     "t6",
     "&\" ",
     "(7y) ",
     ""}
```

A 3rd example, to exemplify a tricky split where only the first case should be ignored:

```
string text = "!!\"!!\"!!\"";
string pattern = "!!";

string[] result = Regex.Split(text, pattern, RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

Wanted **result** after split (2 splits, 3 strings):

```
    {"",
     "\"!!\"",
     "\""}
```

Actual **result** (3 splits, 4 strings):

```
    {"",
     "\"",
     "\"",
     "\"",}
```

So, how do I move from **pattern** to a new pattern that achieves the desired **result**?

Sidenote: If you're going to mark someone's question as duplicate (and I have nothing against that), at least point them to the right answer, not to some random post (yes, I'm looking at you, Mr. Avinash Raj)...

Comment: did you delete your previous question?

Comment: You have re-posted the same question as was closed as a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3147836/335858). If you think your question is **not** a duplicate of this question, please explain it in the body of the question.

Comment: @AvinashRaj [Yes, he did](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32796029/335858).

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/rB6hG3/1

Comment: Yes, I did delete it, because no amount of edits will "UnDuplicate" it.
As you can see by the third example, the answer provided in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147836/c-sharp-regex-split-commas-outside-quotes), which is the same as [here](https://regex101.com/r/rB6hG3/1), will not work.

Comment: Could you explain *how do I move from pattern to a new pattern*? Do you mean to ask to fix each of the 3 regexes? 3-in-1 question? Or do you want to combine them into 1?

Comment: If you have a string `abc , def , a", "d , oioi` the result between `a", "d`  would not be `a` and `d` because the comma is within the quote which you said **ignore**. The result would be `ad`. I recommend you redefine the requirements; they seem to conflict with the result examples you gave.

Comment: [First](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2c(%3f%3d(%3f%3a%5b%5e%22%5d*%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%22)*%5b%5e%22%5d*%24)&i=abc+%2c+def+%2c+a%22+%2c+%22d+%2c+oioi&o=e) and [second](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%25(%3f%3d(%3f%3a%5b%5e%22%5d*%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%22)*%5b%5e%22%5d*%24)&i=a%252%25+6y+%25+%22ad%25t6%25%26%22+%25(7y)+%25&o=e) can be considered duplicates of the question mentioned in the deleted post. The 3rd one contains 3 double quotes, and it is difficult to tell what is really *inside* them.

Answer (score 2):

The rules are more or less like in a csv line except that:

- the delimiter can be a single character, but it can be a string or a pattern too (in these last cases items must be trimmed if they start or end with the last or first possible tokens of the pattern delimiter),
- an orphan quote is allowed for the last item.

First, when you want to separate items (to split) with a little advanced rules, the split method is no more a good choice. The split method is only handy for simple situations, not for your case. *(even without orphan quotes, using split with `,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)` is a very bad idea since the number of steps needed to parse the string grows exponentially with the string size.)*

The other approach consists to capture items. That is more simple and faster. (bonus: it checks the format of the whole string at the same time).

Here is a general way to do it:

```
^
(?>
  (?:delimiter | start_of_the_string)
  (
      simple_part
      (?>
          (?: quotes | delim_first_letter_1 | delim_first_letter_2 | etc. )
          simple_part
      )*
  )
)+
$
```

Example with `\s*,\s*` as delimiter:

```
^
# non-capturing group for one delimiter and one item
(?>
    (?: \s*,\s* | ^ ) # delimiter or start of the string
                      # (eventually change "^" to "^ \s*" to trim the first item)

    # capture group 1 for the item 
    (   # simple part of the item (maybe empty):
        [^\s,"]* # all that is not the quote character or one of the  possible first
                 # character of the delimiter
        # edge case followed by a simple part
        (?>
            (?: # edge cases
                " [^"]* (?:"|$) # a quoted part or an orphan quote in the last item (*)
              |   # OR
                (?> \s+ ) # start of the delimiter
                (?!,)     # but not the delimiter
            )

            [^\s,"]* # simple part
        )*
    )
)+
$
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3E(%3F%3A%5Cs*%2C%5Cs*%7C%5E%5Cs*)(%5B%5E%5Cs%2C%22%5D*(%3F%3E(%3F%3A%22%5B%5E%22%5D*(%3F%3A%22%7C%24)%7C(%3F%3E%5Cs%2B)(%3F!%2C))%5B%5E%5Cs%2C%22%5D*)*))%2B%24&i=abc%20%2C%20def%20%2C%20a%22%20%2C%20%22d%20%2C%20oioi%2C%2C%20asd%22sdf%22%2C%20jk%2Cfg%22df) *(click on the table link)*

The pattern is designed for the `Regex.Match` method since it describes all the string. All items are available in group 1 since the .net regex flavor is able to store repeated capture groups.

This example can be easily adapted to all cases.

*(*) if you want to allow escaped quotes inside quoted parts, you can use one more time `simple_part (?: edge_case simple_part)*`* instead of `" [^"]* (?:"|$)`, 
i.e: `"[^\\"]* (?: \\. [^\\"]*)* (?:"|$)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a two step process and it has been overthought trying to make it a one step regex.

---

**Steps**

1. Simply remove any quotes from a string.
2. Split on the target character(s).

**Example of Process**

I will split on the `,` for step 2.

```
var data = string.Format("abc , def , a{0}, {0}d , oioi", "\"");

 // `\x22` is hex for a quote (") which for easier reading in C# editing.
var stage1 = Regex.Replace(data, @"\x22", string.Empty);

// abc , def , a", "d , oioi
// becomes
// abc , def , a, d , oioi

Regex.Matches(stage1, @"([^\s,]+)[\s,]*")
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(mt => mt.Groups[1].Value )
```

**Result**

[image]