# Using Spaces in Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, csv

I'm having a lot of difficulty with spaces in Java while using regular expressions.  The assignment is to split a comma-separated input string like,

```
J,Project report,"F, G, I",1
```

into separate strings containing:
J
Project report
F, G, I
1
if that makes sense. I'm using a Scanner to split the string. My regex (and code) I'm using is.

```
while (t.hasNext("([a-zA-Z0-9]| )*(\".+\")*,?")) { 
    System.out.println("t.next is : " + t.next());
```

...where t is a scanner of the input string as described above.  But this does not appear to ever resort to true as nothing is printed.  The closest I can get to working is just using simply ".*" as my regex, but that will separate at spaces and I need to separate only at the commas NOT within quotation marks. Can anyone assist? Thank you.

Comment: must you use regular expressions?  they are perhaps not the best tool for the job here

Comment: No it's not required, but simply using a "," as a delimiter won't work, as F, G, and I will be separated when they are to be part of one string. This can admittedly be simpler, but I am not sure how to approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")
```

Reference: [Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

Also, http://regexpal.com/ is a really neat and useful tool when it comes to testing out regexes :)

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated! I can't believe I didn't find that while searching before. That is a big help.

Answer (score 1):

This CAN be done with a regular expression, but a regular expression is perhaps not the best tool for the job.  The expression you are going to end up with is going to be hard to read/maintain, and isn't necessarily going to be any more efficient.

Without going into too much detail, as this is your homework, not mine,  I'd think about this another way:

You need a stateful scanner.  You have two states, "i'm in the middle of quotes" and "i'm not".  Scan the string character by character and each character will cause you either to accumulate a future result, emit a result or change states.

If this needs to be more robust, it might need to have even more states, for example. if you need to also parse something like:

```
a,"b\"c",d
```

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be very robust. This is the entire file: http://pastebin.com/imej2AYM
I don't need to worry about anything else besides these cases. I like the state idea too.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the suggestion that a robust third parter CSV library is a way to go. However, here is how you can use `Scanner`.

```
Scanner t = new Scanner(new File("test.csv"));
t.useDelimiter(',(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)');
while( t.hasNext() ) {
    System.out.println(t.next());
}
```

I used the regex from @Hristo answer.

Comment: Thank you JRideout! Third-party is good but it's always nice to be able to solve a problem yourself without handing it off to someone else to finish - I want to understand what's going on and be able to understand the gory details to make me a better programmer. But maybe I shouldn't be using Java in that case? ;) The assignment wasn't actually mine, I was helping a friend, but this will help a lot thank you!

Answer (score 1):

CSV files are more complex than they at first appear. For example in German countries the file separator is normally the ";" character..... While I understand your assigment was to use regexp's, don't waste your time when solving this problem for real.

My tool of choice is [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). Here's a groovy script (I leave you to convet it to Java) that parses your string:

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVParser

@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='net.sf.opencsv', module='opencsv', version='2.3')
])

CSVParser csv = new CSVParser()
String[] result = csv.parseLine('J,Project report,"F, G, I",1')

assert result[0] == "J"
assert result[1] == "Project report"
assert result[2] == "F, G, I"
assert result[3] == "1"
```

The CSVReader object provides ways to iterate over the file contents:

```
new File("data.csv").withReader { reader ->
    CSVReader csv = new CSVReader(reader);

    csv.readAll().each {
        println it[0]
        println it[1]
        println it[2]
        println it[3]
    }
}
```

Comment: The assignment wasn't actually to use regex and it actually isn't even my assignment haha. My friend needed help for his software engineering class, and it was bothering me that I wasn't able to help solve the problem, hence my thread. But keeping in mind this library would probably be beneficial for both my friend and I.  Thanks! I almost picked this response as the answer. Very informative!