# Replace comma with semicolon in between quotas

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssis

I have a csv file from which i am getting the data into a table.
Example:
"ABC",1,"Apple"
The requirement is that the strings will be inside the quotas " "  and integer will be without quotes.
The above  line will split into three columns.
i am using stream reader class to split the line into columns using line.split(','). It was working fine unfortunately i got a record in a file where there is a comma in between the string quotes like these 
"ABC,DEF,ghi",2,"Orange". 
So instead of 3 columns now they are acting as five columns and all the conversion are failing.
Can any one help me in writing the script in C# which will replace the comma between the quotas into semicolon and don't touch the comma in between the columns.

Thank you.

Comment: how do you escape `"` in those strings, or can you expect them to not contain `"`?

Comment: is the file is subject to change you can may want to create an enum that defines the file header layout.. and check for extra columns I've done this on my last project otherwise you will have to check the length of each string after doing the split becasue ABC,DEF,ghi" should split into 3 columns instead of 1 is can you follow what I am talking about doing.. then you would have to concat the DEF ghi as part of ABC

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your CSV might be RFC 4180 compliant. Use an RFC 4180 parser. Many of those exist. Check this one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Comment: i am not using any parser  i am using C# custom script in script component in ssis

Comment: so why does this have a VB tag if you are using C#

Answer (score 2):

This question is answered here:
[Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

You could use the same regular expression `",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"`
and use the C# method `Regex.Split()`.

Comment: hi i dont have Regex class which using statement i need to use to get i am a beginner in C# please bare with me

Comment: You do have a regular expression class. You would need to add a `using System.Text.RegularExpressions`