# how to split string by space but escape spaces inside quotes (in java)?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
"Video or movie"    "parent"    "Media or entertainment"    "1" "1" "1" "0" "0"
```

I would like to split it by the spaces but the space inside the quote should be ignored.
So the splitted strings should be:

```
"Video or movie"
"parent"
"Media or entertainment"
"1"
...
```

The language is java.

Comment: how does a `"` get escaped in your scenario?  `"he said \"hi\"."`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this should do the job for you:

```
   final String s = "\"Video or movie\"    \"parent\"    \"Media or entertainment\"    \"1\" \"1\" \"1\" \"0\" \"0\"";
        final String[] t = s.split("(?<=\") *(?=\")");
        for (final String x : t) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
```

output:

```
"Video or movie"
"parent"
"Media or entertainment"
"1"
"1"
"1"
"0"
"0"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
Patter pt = Pattern.compile("(\"[^\"]*\")");
```

Just keep in mind that this also capture `""` (empty string).

**TESTING:**

```
String text="\"Video or movie\"    \"parent\"    \"Media or entertainment\"    \"1\" \"1\" \"1\" \"0\" \"0\"";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\"[^\"]*\")").matcher(text);
while(m.find())
    System.out.printf("Macthed: [%s]%n", m.group(1));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Macthed: ["Video or movie"]
Macthed: ["parent"]
Macthed: ["Media or entertainment"]
Macthed: ["1"]
Macthed: ["1"]
Macthed: ["1"]
Macthed: ["0"]
Macthed: ["0"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this question. You may be able to adapt its solution to ignore the spaces in the quotes rather than the commas.

[Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting, just match things that are not space.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"|\\S+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split by **"[ ]+"** instead? (including the quotes)

You're likely to need to add in missing "'s if they aren't at the start or end of the string.