# Regular expression with String.split()

Tags: java, regex, string, split

How can I implement regular expression to String.split() to seperate values by spaces and ignore double quoted text?

Like in the below example.

```
hello "Luis Anderson" your age is 30 and u will get $30
```

this, list of strings:

```
'hello', '"Luis Anderson"', 'your', 'age', 'is', '30', 'and', 'u', 'will', 'get', '$30'
```

The problem is that when I'm using String.split(), it takes in consideration also phrase between "Luis Enderson" and spliting it in 2 strings.

If you got any other ideas which not include usage of regular expression please explain it, thanks.

SIMILAR QUESTION [how to split string by space but escape spaces inside quotes (in java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945113/how-to-split-string-by-space-but-escape-spaces-inside-quotes-in-java)

Comment: I'm not so good with regular expression but I'm trying to read line, like u see on example, and split it to get tokens, the problem is that when im spliting by space it take all spaces and i dont want consider spaces in "phrase", my attemp of regex "/\"[\w]+\"\"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945113/how-to-split-string-by-space-but-escape-spaces-inside-quotes-in-java

Comment: @Thihara, thanks you. I did search for it but didnt see anywhere, maybe bcuz of syntax question, thanks.

Comment: @user1768615 In question provided by Thihara OP was trying to split on spaces surrounded only by quotation marks like `" "`. Your question seems to be different.

Comment: @Pshemo, but it is very similar and I dont want spam stackoverflow with similar question, but if u consider it different I will edite it, just confirm me it, please

Comment: @user1768615 In my opinion your question is different, but if you are able to create solution using that question then I don't mind leaving your edit as it is :)

Comment: @Pshemo, alright so i take edite part off, maybe for somebody it will be useful.

Comment: You could use a csv parser using space as a separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = "hello \"Luis Anderson\" your age is 30 and u will get $30";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\s|^)(\".*?\"|\\S*)(?=$|\\s)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

outputs:

```
hello
"Luis Anderson"
your
age
is
30
and
u
will
get
$30
```

you can handle the text in array or List, or whatever

Comment: is it possible to reach such result without using `pattern&matcher`?

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't have to be regex, then you can do it in **one iteration** over String characters.

```
String data = "hello \"Luis Anderson\" your age is 30 and u will get $30";

List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean insideQuote = false;

for (char c : data.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '"')
        insideQuote = !insideQuote;
    if (c == ' ' && !insideQuote) {
        tokens.add(sb.toString());
        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
    } else
        sb.append(c);
}
tokens.add(sb.toString());// last word

System.out.println(tokens);
```

output: `[hello, "Luis Anderson", your, age, is, 30, and, u, will, get, $30]`

Comment: This is what I would have done, but only because my regex-fu is not as strong as Kent's.

Comment: Ehm, this is nice piece of code but I'm wondering if its possible to make with regular expression to save space and make it on more gentile way.

Comment: @user1768615 If there are no nested quotes like `a "b "c d" e" f` then it is possible. You can try this way `split("\\s(?!(\\S+\\s+)*\\S+\")|\\s(?=\")")`. If nested quotes are possible (at any level) then regex is not best tool for this.