# scala: split string by commnas, ignoring commas between quotes

Tags: regex, parsing, scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

It's easier to show some code

I have the following:

```
scala> val a = """op1,"op2.1,op2.2",,op4""".split(",")
a: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(op1, "op2.1, op2.2", "", op4)

scala> a.foreach( println )
op1
"op2.1
op2.2"

op4
```

I'd like to get

```
scala> val a = """op1,"op2.1,op2.2",,op4""".split(",")
a: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(op1, "op2.1, op2.2", "", op4)

scala> a.foreach( println )
op1
op2.1, op2.2

op4
```

But I can't figure out what regular expression to use to split the string

-- edit --

I found the answer in this question: [Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

Comment: Are you processing input data in CSV format?

Comment: thanks for the link, m.buettner, it worked great!!!

Answer (score 16):

Split with this regexp, it should work: `,(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)`

Comment: That was perfect!