# How split a text with a expression use in values

Tags: android, sql

I try split values of sql for modify values (DATE, boolean, ...).
    For example, I have the values:

```
('im a value','im a second value with, test',478,20/05/2010 16:56:32)
```

**How i can split the value for had only 4 values:**

- 'im a value'
- 'im a second value with, test'
- 478
- 20/05/2010 16:56:32

and **not 5 values:**

- 'im a value'
- 'im a second value with
- test'
- 478
- 20/05/2010 16:56:32

Thanks

**edit:**

new exemple:

```
  INSERT INTO ACCES (id,type,com, date,make) VALUES (478,'action','test commentaire, new test',20/05/2010 16:56:3,False);
```

result

```
 INSERT INTO ACCES (id,type,com, date,make) VALUES (478,'action','test commentaire, new test',1274367363,0);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, there are only two values, the comma is part of the second value. The apostrophe in SQL is a field delimiter.

Comment: It's like he's getting it all as a String and trying to `split` on the `,`, effectively chopping off at the comma in-between the `'` too.

Comment: We need more details about your problem. How / where are stored those values (uniaue string, database etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this iteratively, or you can do it this way:

[Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes#answer-1757107)

In short, you split with a regular expression:

```
line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

Comment: tanks for me the regular expression is ",(?=([^\']*\'[^\']*\')*[^\']*$)"

Answer (score 0):

I know only one way to do that.

1. Split input string by "," to array
2. If I string starts with "'" and (I+1) string end with "'" then combine it to I element
3. Remove I+1 element

If you need realisation, I can write it later

Comment: your idea is interessant, i need realisation a value can contains more one ","...