# Java regular expression escaped commas

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a csv file that I would like to use the `String split()` method on. I want each element of the array returned by `split()` to be the comma separated values in the csv. However, there are other commas in the csv file.

Fortunately, these other commas are escaped like `'\,'`

I am having trouble getting the right regex for the `split()` method. I want to split by commas that are not preceded by the escape character.

My current code is:

```
String[] columns = new String[CONST];
columns = someString.split("*^\\,*");
```

To me this says: split by a comma but the character before the comma must not be the escape character. Any number of characters before or after the comma are allowed.

1. How do I get the correct regular expression?

Comment: Why are you writing `= new String[CONST]`, only to replace it immediately afterward?

Comment: Also, `CONST` is an _extremely_ poor variable name; it gives no indication of what the variable represents.

Comment: [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) is a very simple csv (comma-separated values) parser library for Java. Configurable separator and quote characters (or use sensible defaults)

Comment: @Brian Roach I do not know regular expressions very well.

Comment: @BrianRoach - Maybe the regex was written by a rabbit?

Comment: Regular expressions *cannot* be trivial used with CSV (of which common forms include [optional] quoting and/or delimiter escapes) - as others have said, use a library.

Comment: I believe Apache Commons also has a CSV parser. Regular expressions are definitely the wrong way to go.

Comment: @pst: I think regex can be used to parse CSV (although the solution is not trivial), but you have to know the exact format to write one that works correctly...

Comment: @nhahtdh "Trivial" is the keyword. There are plenty of SO questions that cover matched/balanced quote [ir]regular expressions. Integrating it into a split is no less complicated nor does it cover the case of an n-escaped separators (as what this question is really about) ..

Comment: I second @PaulVargas's comment. Please just use OpenCSV and be done, and not manually parse CSV with regexes.

Comment: You can replace "\," with a pattern and then split using comma, re-replace back what you split and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

First, comma doesn't have special meaning at the position you are using, therefore you can omit the escape

The biggest problem in your regex is, `*` alone doesn't give you any meaning. `*` means any occurrence of previous token.

So the regex should be

`.*,.*`  (I think escaping the comma should still be fine  `.*\,.*` )

Then, come to usage, you are using the regex in `String.split()`.  `String.split()` expect for the regex for the delimiter.  Therefore you should only pass a `,` as regex.  Having `.*,.*` as "delimiter" is going to give you unexpected result (You may have a try).

Comment: This will bomb the whole string when used with `split`.

Comment: I am only talking about the validity of his regex, and haven't pay attention on where he is using it for (split).  In order to use in split(), simply a comma should work

Answer (score 0):

Since I hit this page on a search, I will answer the question as stated and put the correct pattern (and for completeness):

```
columns = someString.split("[^\\\\],");
```

Note that you need 4 escape characters because you need 2 escape characters to create 1 escape character in a string.  In other words, "\\" creates the string \ .  So "\\\\" creates the string \\, which escapes the escape in the regex to create the char \ in the regex.  Therefore you need 4 escape characters in a string to create one in a regex.  The brackets and the carat are one way to make a not statement (specifically for a single character).

You can also surround CSV entries that you don't want to split with quotes.  Then use the following solution: [Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes).

My personal preference would be to use split over a 3rd party parser because of the environment I code in.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use a parser (to deal with `\\,` `\,` `,`) but using a simple regex can work;

```
jshell> "a,b".split("(?!\\\\),")
$2 ==> String[2] { "a", "b" }
```

How to test things that don't work;

```
jshell> "a,b".split("[^\\\\],")
$1 ==> String[2] { "", "b" }
```

and

```
jshell> "a,b".split("*^\\,*")
|  java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException thrown: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
*^\,*
^
|        at Pattern.error (Pattern.java:1997)
|        at Pattern.sequence (Pattern.java:2172)
|        at Pattern.expr (Pattern.java:2038)
|        at Pattern.compile (Pattern.java:1760)
|        at Pattern.<init> (Pattern.java:1409)
|        at Pattern.compile (Pattern.java:1065)
|        at String.split (String.java:2307)
|        at String.split (String.java:2354)
|        at (#6:1)
```