# split on string

Tags: java

I have a string like this `abc & "def&ghi" & jkl & "mno&pqr"` and want to do a split aroung `&`, but i don't want to split words within double quotes.

Output should be `abc, "def&ghi", jkl, "mno&pqr"`.

I tried doing a `split("&")` on that string, but that's also splitting the words within double quotes.

Whats the best way of doing this?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes), and replace the `,` with a `&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you should use something like a [csv parser](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) since those are programmed exactly to handle the issue of `" "` escaping.

If this is homework and you are not allowed to use production tools, then you should follow the advice in [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

if there was a white space between the & quote like you mentioned above

```
abc & "def&ghi" & jkl & "mno&pqr"
```

then you can use `.split(" & ");` to also trim the white space.

Comment: There could be more spaces before and after `&`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you're right, but it may be the case that input will always have one space before and after the &

Answer (score 0):

I agree that CSV parser is the solution, but as a matter of principle:

```
    String s = "abc & \"def&ghi\" & jkl & \"mno&pqr\"";
    String[] a = s.split("(?=.*[^\"] )&");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

output

```
[abc ,  "def, ghi" ,  jkl ,  "mno&pqr"]
```