# Short way to parse white spaces that are not between commas?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Is there a short way (maybe str.split variation) for parsing a string by white spaces while bypassing when it is between quotes?

example:
this should be split "this is not" and so on

result:

```
[0] - this; [1] - should; [2] - be; [3] - split; [4] - "this is not"; 
[5] - and; [6] - so; [7] - on;
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean "between qoutes".

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes

Comment: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ : For all practical purpose use library for csv parsing:  OpenCSV does lot of good work

Comment: Can data have nested quotes like `aa "bb "cc cc" bb" aa`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String words = input.split(" +(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

It's saying split only if there's an even number of quotes to the right. It doesn't cater for escaped quotes, but that's not hard to do - just becomes very hard to read.

Comment: I'd say matching with Matcher is more flexible than split for this case...

Comment: @nhahtdh what do you mean? Why is flexibility relevant? The task is to split. Why would you use several lines when one call will do it?

Comment: For example - the case when there are odd number of `"`, or the case of `"abc"next to quote`. It is easier to customize the regex than `split`.