# Add variable to ArrayList with custom split

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a string to an `ArrayList<String>` using .add(string). This works, but it separates the variables using a comma (","). This makes it problematic for me later on when I try to split the string, because some of the sentences contain commas.

How do I change the comma to another variable when adding a string to an ArrayList?

Comment: can you post an example string that was added

Comment: You can use  `str.replaceAll('\\,',"something")`

Comment: override `toString` method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes

Comment: @Ruchira: No need to escape `,`, but also no need to use `replaceAll()` to replace text. Use `replace()` instead.

Comment: can you please explain more with some example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is using the `toString` method of the `ArrayList` which will print each of the element of that `ArrayList` separated with commas.

**solution:**

just iterate to all of the `Arraylist` and **append** them using the `String Builder`.

**sample:**

```
    ArrayList<String>  s= new ArrayList<>();
    s.add("adsasd");
    s.add("adsasd");
    s.add("adsasd");
    s.add("adsasd");
    StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s3 : s)
        s2.append(s3+" ");
    System.out.println(s2);
```

**result:**

```
adsasd adsasd adsasd adsasd
```

Answer (score 0):

let ArrayList str contain the list.

```
String myString = str.toString();
myString.replaceAll(",","something");
```

Also you can use String Builder.

You have a ArrayList. I suppose you are doing something with the particular index of the arrayList. So, get that index and then get the String and split it using substring by getting the index of ",". But it this method is not that convenient as your code will be long.