# Replacing mulitple matches between 2 strings using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to do a `Regex.Replace()` to get rid of all the `\r\n` between the `ul` and `/ul` tags.  Now I love writing *RegEx* as much as the next guy, But I can't for the life of me figure out the correct pattern to use. Any one have any idea what the pattern I need to match all instances of `/r/n` between the two tags using *RegEx?*

```
This is a note&nbsp;I am using to display bullets&nbsp;here are some examples\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>somethign</li>\r\n<li>somthing else</li>\r\n</ul>
```

Comment: Does the string contain newlines, or does it literally contain the string `\r\n`?

Comment: new lines.  It is stored exactly as printed above

Comment: Almost a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407169/c-sharp-replace-with-regex/27407783#27407783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a way to accomplish this is a pure regular expression, but one option is to use a regex and a custom match evaluator:

```
value = Regex.Replace(value, "<ul>.*?</ul>", (match) =>
    {
        return match.Value.Replace("\r\n", "");
    }, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

And as a side point:  Once you start thinking about parsing HTML fragments, you should consider using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack).  It's not always necessary, but it can save trouble as you get more and more complex requirements.

Comment: I like your style.  I tried something similar to this but it seems the singleline option is key.  Thanks my friend, you made my life easier