# Java - explain this regular expression (",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1)

Tags: java, regex

I am separating a string "foo,bar,c;qual="baz,blurb",d;junk="quux,syzygy"" by commas but want to keep the commas in the quotes. This question was answered in this [Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes) question but it fails to fully explain how the poster created this piece of code which is:

```
line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);
```

OK so I do understand some of what is going on but there is a bit that is confusing me. I know the first comma is for matching.

Then

```
        (?=
```

is a forward search.

Then the first part is grouped

```
  ([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\").
```

This where I get confused. So the first part

```
  [^\"]*
```

means that beginning of any line with quotes separate tokens zero or more times.

Then comes \". Now is this like opening a quote in string or is it saying match this quote?

Then it repeats the exact same line of code, why?

```
      ([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")
```

In the second part adds the same code again to explain that it must finish with quotes.

Can someone explain the part i am not getting?

Comment: `^` inside square brackets mean not. `\"` means `"` but the backslash is there as an escape character. So `[^\"]*` matches any string that does not contain `"`.

Comment: Thanks, it would help if i knew that part. I still don't understand the part after [^\"] though

Comment: @M.Shaw it must be `[^\"]*` matches any character but not of `"`, zero or more times.

Comment: `[^\"]` is any string without `"`. `\"` matches `"`. So basically `([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")` matches a string that contains 2 `"` and the last character is `"`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Which is basically any string that doesn't contain `"`.

Comment: Always thought regex is a write only thing ... Noone can read a regex, only write ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^\"]` is any string without ". \" matches ". So basically ([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\") matches a string that contains 2 `"` and the last character is `"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think they do a pretty good job of explaining later in the answer:

`[^\"]` is match other than quote.
`\"` is quote.

So this part `([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")` is

1. `[^\"]*` match other than quote 0 or more times
2. `\"` match quote, yes this is the opening quote
3. `[^\"]*` match other than quote 0 or more times
4. `\"` match quote, closing quote

They only require the first `[^\"]*` because they do not start with a quote, their example input is like `a="abc",b="d,ef"`. If you were parsing `"abc","d,ef"` you wouldn't need it.

Comment: Yes, the poster does explain what is going on well, it did not help that I was a little of base. I just didn't really understand the syntax

Answer (score 0):

here is your string /,(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)/

here is the readout from https://regex101.com/

```
, matches the character , literally
(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
1st Capturing group ([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
[^\"]* match a single character not present in the list below
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\" matches the character " literally
\" matches the character " literally
[^\"]* match a single character not present in the list below
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\" matches the character " literally
\" matches the character " literally
[^\"]* match a single character not present in the list below
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\" matches the character " literally
$ assert position at end of the string
```