# Scala CSV parser removed spaces

Tags: regex, scala, csv

I am trying to parse the following line to an data array:

```
"John,Doe","123 Main St","Brown Eyes"
```

I wanted to have an array `data` like below:

```
data(0) = John,Doe
data(1) = 123 Main St
data(2) = Brown Eyes
```

I used the following CSV parser from website:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object CSV extends RegexParsers {
  override protected val whiteSpace = """[ \t]""".r

  def COMMA   = ","
  def DQUOTE  = "\""
  def DQUOTE2 = "\"\"" ^^ { case _ => "\"" }
  def CR      = "\r"
  def LF      = "\n"
  def CRLF    = "\r\n"
  def TXT     = "[^\",\r\n]".r

  def file: Parser[List[List[String]]] = repsep(record, CRLF) <~ opt(CRLF)
  def record: Parser[List[String]] = rep1sep(field, COMMA)
  def field: Parser[String] = (escaped|nonescaped)
  def escaped: Parser[String] = (DQUOTE~>((TXT|COMMA|CR|LF|DQUOTE2)*)<~DQUOTE) ^^ { case ls => ls.mkString("")}
  def nonescaped: Parser[String] = (TXT*) ^^ { case ls => ls.mkString("") }

  def parse(s: String) = parseAll(file, s) match {
    case Success(res, _) => res
    case _ => List[List[String]]()
  }
}
```

Then all the spaces are trimmed. The data array actually look like:

```
data(0) = John,Doe
data(1) = 123MainSt
data(2) = BrownEyes
```

---

How do I avoid such unwanted "removing whitespace" for the CSV parser? Thanks!

Comment: There is an error in this approach. It specifically corrupts on column values which contain a valid line break. Because of so many issues, even in the presence of an RFC for the .csv MIME-type, I strongly suggest you use a well-maintained RFC driven native Scala library which optimally handles this problem, kantan.csv: https://nrinaudo.github.io/kantan.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this job in one line :

```
line.split((",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")
```

The regex is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes) and then apply this on all lines of your file. This will split only the comma outside two quotes.

Code to parse the csv File :

`scala> scala.io.Source.fromFile("toto.csv").getLines.toList.map(_.split((",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"))`

Comment: That's code to parse a subset of CSV file. What happens if one of the values contains a double quote?

Comment: Per @NicolasRinaudo's comment, There is an error in this approach. It specifically corrupts on column values which contain a valid line break. Because of so many issues, even in the presence of an RFC for the .csv MIME-type, I strongly suggest you use a well-maintained RFC driven native Scala library which optimally handles this problem, kantan.csv: https://nrinaudo.github.io/kantan.csv

Answer (score 1):

Your code says to take a sequence of escaped or nonescaped tokens and join them with no intervening space:

```
...* ^^ { case ls => ls.mkString("") }
```

Per the docs for `RegexParsers`,

- The parsing methods call the method skipWhitespace (defaults to true) and, if true, skip any whitespace before each parser is called.
- Protected val whiteSpace returns a regex that identifies whitespace.

Try turning off `skipWhitespace`:

```
override protected val skipWhitespace = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason for hand-writing a CSV-decoder instead of using one of many existing, well-tested ones? Like `OpenCSV` or `Jackson CSV module`. It should be much simpler to use an existing lib, and you wouldn't bump into various issues in trying to unescape quotes, trim (or not) spaces, and so on.

Comment: Agreed. Because of so many issues, even in the presence of an RFC for the .csv MIME-type, I strongly suggest you use a well-maintained RFC driven native Scala library which optimally handles this problem, kantan.csv: https://nrinaudo.github.io/kantan.csv

Answer (score 1):

The precise answer to your question was given by Robert Starling: set `skipWhitespace` to `false`.

The answer to the question "how do I parse CSV reliably?", which I'm assuming is what you really want to know, is "use a dedicated library".

You can use one of the Java ones - opencsv, commons-csv, jackson-csv, univocity... or one of the Scala ones - product-collections, purecsv, kantan.csv...

Don't write your own without a good reason - I wrote tabulate because I needed better type handling than was available at the time - and if you do, don't use one of the Scala parser combinator libraries: they load the whole data as a string in memory before parsing, which doesn't scale at all when your data starts growing.

If you *must* write your own and want to use a parser combinator library (because, let's face it, it's a fun problem and those libraries are cool), consider fastparse instead, or parboiled, which are both of a higher quality than the standard Scala one.