# Java 8, how can I implement a switch statement using streams?

Tags: java, java-8, switch-statement, java-stream

I have a text file `imgui.ini` containing:

```
[Debug]
Pos=7,79
Size=507,392
Collapsed=0

[ImGui Demo]
Pos=320,5
Size=550,680
Collapsed=0
```

For each "element" I always have `Pos`, `Size` and `Collapsed` and I need to read them.

I would like to use, if possible, java 8 streams.

Is it possible to simulate a switch statement behaviour?

```
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(context.io.iniFilename))) {

        ...
/*
    switch(string) {

        case "Pos":
            settings.pos = value;
            break;

        case "Size":
            settings.size = value;
            break;

        case "Collapsed":
            settings.collapsed = value;
            break;
    }
*/

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear - what are you trying to switch on? It sounds like you might want to *first* write a method which reads the lines and returns a `Map<String, ConfigurationBlock>` (where `ConfigurationBlock` is your own type, or maybe use `Properties`).

Comment: Start by showing what you want to do with a normal switch statement without the Stream

Comment: I think stream is ideal when the order of inputs is insignificant. In your ini example, however, the order of lines is critical. Thus, the element of the top-level stream should not be lines of text, but config sections. And each section consists of a stream of order-insensitive lines of text.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks so, @MaartenBodewes.. I was kind of hoping there was a few-lines-elegant method

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way to parse such a file (without using dedicated 3rd party libraries), is via the regex API, and its front-end class `Scanner`. Unfortunately, the best operations to implement it via Stream API, are currently missing. Namely, [`Matcher.results()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) and [`Scanner.findAll(…)`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findAll-java.util.regex.Pattern-) are not there yet. So unless we want to wait until Java 9, we have to create similar methods for a Java 8 compatible solution:

```
public static Stream<MatchResult> findAll(Scanner s, Pattern pattern) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<MatchResult>(
            1000, Spliterator.ORDERED|Spliterator.NONNULL) {
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super MatchResult> action) {
            if(s.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0)!=null) {
                action.accept(s.match());
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
    }, false);
}
public static Stream<MatchResult> results(Matcher m) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<MatchResult>(
            m.regionEnd()-m.regionStart(), Spliterator.ORDERED|Spliterator.NONNULL) {
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super MatchResult> action) {
            if(m.find()) {
                action.accept(m.toMatchResult());
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Using methods with a similar semantic allows us to replace their usage with the standard API methods, once Java 9 is released and becomes commonplace.

Using these two operations, you can parse your file using

```
Pattern groupPattern=Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]([^\\[]*)");
Pattern attrPattern=Pattern.compile("(.*?)=(.*)\\v");
Map<String, Map<String, String>> m;
try(Scanner s=new Scanner(Paths.get(context.io.iniFilename))) {
    m = findAll(s, groupPattern).collect(Collectors.toMap(
        gm -> gm.group(1),
        gm -> results(attrPattern.matcher(gm.group(2)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(am->am.group(1), am->am.group(2)))));
}
```

the resulting map `m` holds all information, mapping from the group names to another map holding the key/value pairs, i.e. you can print an equivalent `.ini` file using:

```
m.forEach((group,attr)-> {
    System.out.println("["+group+"]");
    attr.forEach((key,value)->System.out.println(key+"="+value));
});
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's way more readable and maintainable than the switch statement in the question.

Answer (score 9):

Focusing on the question "is there a way to simulate switch statement behavior", I think the answer is that you could, with a little effort. I asked myself that a couple of years ago, and did the following as an exercise (and then never used it again):

```
private static <T> Predicate<T> testAndConsume(Predicate<T> pred, Consumer<T> cons) {
    return t -> {
        boolean result = pred.test(t);
        if (result) cons.accept(t);
        return result;
    };
}

public static class SwitchConsumer<T> {
    Predicate<T> conditionalConsumer;
    private SwitchConsumer(Predicate<T> pred) {
        conditionalConsumer = pred;
    }

    public static <C> SwitchConsumer<C> inCase(Predicate<C> pred, Consumer<C> cons) {
        return new SwitchConsumer<>(testAndConsume(pred, cons));
    }

    public SwitchConsumer<T> elseIf(Predicate<T> pred, Consumer<T> cons) {
        return new SwitchConsumer<>(conditionalConsumer.or(testAndConsume(pred,cons)));
    }

    public Consumer<T> elseDefault(Consumer<T> cons) {
        return testAndConsume(conditionalConsumer.negate(),cons)::test;   // ::test converts Predicate to Consumer
    }
}
```

`testAndConsume` composes a `Predicate` and a `Consumer`, creating a `Predicate` that returns the same value but calls the `Consumer` as a side-effect if the value is true.  That becomes the basis for each "case" in the "switch". Each "case" is strung together by `Predicate.or()`, which provides the short-circuiting "else-if" nature of the switch.  Finally, the composed `Predicate` is turned into a `Consumer` by adding `::test` to the `Predicate`.

Applying it to your code snippet, it looks like this:

```
    Stream.of("Pos=320,5", "Size=550,680", "Collapsed=0")
            .map(s -> s.split("="))
            .forEach(SwitchConsumer.<String[]>
                    inCase(arr -> "Pos".equals(arr[0]), arr -> settings.pos = arr[1])
                    .elseIf(arr -> "Size".equals(arr[0]), arr -> settings.size = arr[1])
                    .elseIf(arr -> "Collapsed".equals(arr[0]), arr -> settings.collapsed = arr[1])
                    .elseDefault(arr -> {}));
```

That's about as switch-ish as it can get without an actual switch in a `Consumer` body.

Answer (score 4):

Attempt:

```
try {
        Path file = Paths.get("G:\\tmp", "img.ini");
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file);

        lines.filter(line->{
            if("pos".equalsIgnoreCase(line.split("=")[0])){
                //process pos line here
                System.out.println("pos"+line);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }).filter(line->{
            System.out.println("2"+line);
            if("Collapsed".equalsIgnoreCase(line.split("=")[0])){
                //process Collapsed line here
                System.out.println("Collapsed"+line);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }).filter(line->{
            System.out.println("3"+line);
            if("Size".equalsIgnoreCase(line.split("=")[0])){
                //process Size line here
                System.out.println("Size"+line);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }).forEach(line->{
            //settings = new Settings();
        });;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to read your config file:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("D:\\Development\\workspace\\Application\\src\\main\\resources\\init.txt");
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));

        Map<String, Config> configMap = Stream.of(content.split("\\n\\r"))
            .map(config -> Arrays.asList(config.split("\\r")))
            .collect(HashMap<String, Config>::new, (map, list) -> {
                String header = list.get(0);
                String pos = list.get(1);
                String size = list.get(2);
                String collapsed = list.get(3);
                map.put(header, new Config(pos.substring(pos.indexOf("=") + 1), size.substring(size.indexOf("=") + 1), collapsed.substring(collapsed.indexOf("=") + 1)));
            }, (m, u) -> {});

        System.out.println(configMap);
    }
}

class Config {
    public String pos;
    public String size;
    public String collapsed;

    public Config(String pos, String size, String collapsed) {
        this.pos = pos;
        this.size = size;
        this.collapsed = collapsed;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Config{" +  "pos='" + pos + '\'' + ", size='" + size + '\'' + 
               ", collapsed='" + collapsed + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

Result will be map:

```
{
    [Debug]=Config{pos='7,79', size='507,392', collapsed='0'}, 
    [ImGui Demo]=Config{pos='320,5', size='550,680', collapsed='0'}
}
```

Comment: Why would you hardcode the line endings? Just to ensure it won't work on a Mac or Linux? And why use backslashes instead of forward slashes in the path? Just so you get to escape them?