# Split list of words using streams in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, java-8, java-stream

I am having this method that takes a number of lists, which contain lines of books. I am combing them to a stream to then iterate over them to split on all non-letter's `\\P{L}`.

Is there a way to avoid the for-each loop and process this within a stream?

```
private List<String> getWordList(List<String>... lists) {
        List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();

        Stream<String> combinedStream = Stream.of(lists)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream);
        List<String> combinedLists = combinedStream.collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (String line: combinedLists) {
            wordList.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split("\\P{L}")));
        }

        return wordList;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having stream, you can simply "`flatMap`" further and return the result:

```
return combinedStream
        .flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split("\\P{L}")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To put it altogether:

```
private List<String> getWordList(List<String>... lists) {
    return Stream.of(lists)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split("\\P{L}")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to introduce so many variables :

```
private List<String> getWordList(List<String>... lists) {

    return Stream.of(lists) // Stream<Stream<String>>
                 .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Stream<String> 
                 .flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\P{L}")::splitAsStream) //Stream<String>     
                 .collect(toList()); // List<String>
}
```

As underlined by Holger, `.flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\P{L}")::splitAsStream)`
should be favored over `.flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\P{L}")))` to spare array allocation and pattern compilation performed for each element of the stream.

Comment: As explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40933002/2711488), it’s recommended to use `.flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\P{L}") ::splitAsStream)`, this avoids recompiling the pattern for every stream element and does not populate a potentially large intermediate array.

Comment: @Holger Thank you very much for this reference. I didn't not still see this one from Java 8. But I don't like very much the method reference in this case `(Pattern.splitAsStream(String)` is not common to use for me at least) but according to your comment in the other post, it is required and I get it. We could also compile the pattern outside the stream but well not terrible either.

Comment: Well, you can also move the pattern to a constant like `static final Pattern NON_LETTER_CHARS = Pattern.compile("\\P{L}");` and then use either `.flatMap(NON_LETTER_CHARS::splitAsStream)` or `.flatMap(s -> NON_LETTER_CHARS.splitAsStream(s))`. In the end, you also have to know about the regex engine when using `s.split("\\P{L}")`.

Comment: Indeed That is that I referenced in my comment edit, sorry. It is a way but that it is not terrible either.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine all the list and `flatMap` for result

```
private List<String> getWordList(List<String>... lists) {
    return Stream.of(lists)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split("\\P{L}")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: `str` is not a String here but a `List`. So `List.split()` cannot compile.  You miss an intermediary operation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54969149/270371