# What is a preferred method to get stream of tokens from a string?

Tags: java, split, java-stream, token

We have a long string with numbers or words separated by space.
We need to get stream of them. What is a preferred method?

I know two options:

1. Arrays(str.split(“ “)).stream();
2. new Scanner(str).tokens();

Both return a stream of strings.
Which option is better?

Any other methods?

Comment: I'd go with the stream. I wouldn't want to open a new Scanner.

Comment: In the reference implementation, the `Scanner(String)` constructor does not utilize the fact that this is already an in-memory `String`, but creates a `StringReader`, following the same logic as reading from an external source. In other words, it’s horribly inefficient. Beyond this new, discouraged option, it’s the same question as [How to split a String into a Stream of Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40932813/2711488)

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid, but not sure about the performance.
Another option is to use StringTokenizer:

```
Collections.list(new StringTokenizer(str)).stream()
```

It provides more ways to customize the tokens.

Edit: no need to pass the white space delimiter since it's the default.

Comment: I know about StringTokinizer but never use it. 
Is it still actual? It come from Java 1.0. Anyway thanks for one more method!

Comment: [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) clearly states: _`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead._

Comment: Thanks @AlexRudenko for the heads up, I will update your comment.