# Java 8 Streams parsing to Integer

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Does it exist better way to parse String to Integer using stream than this :

```
 String line = "1 2 3 4 5";
List<Integer> elements = Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")).mapToInt(x -> Integer.parseInt(x))
    .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the input string contains space-separated things that can each be parsed to an `int`? What if one fails? What should happen then?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can eliminate one step if you parse the String directly to Integer:

```
String line = "1 2 3 4 5";
List<Integer> elements = Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")).map(Integer::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or you can stick to primitive types, which give better performance, by creating an `int` array instead of a `List<Integer>`:

```
int[] elements = Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray ();
```

You can also replace

```
Arrays.stream(line.split(" "))
```

with

```
Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(line)
```

I'm not sure which is more efficient, though.

Answer (score 4):

There's one more way to do it that will be available since java-9 via `Scanner#findAll`:

```
int[] result = scan.findAll(Pattern.compile("\\d+"))
                   .map(MatchResult::group)
                   .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                   .toArray();
```

Comment: Hi Eugene! I've seen you've answered at least one similar question using this same approach. Could you please kindly explain why you need to use `map(MatchResult::group)` in the returned stream? I mean, I know I can go to the docs and find out, but maybe it's better for future readers if you explain this approach a little bit. Thanks!

Comment: I fail to see where the line containing the space-separated ints is parsed. Can you point scanners to read from strings?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner it's the first matched group in the regex... with index `0`. that's what you get when you use `group()`. if you need another group, you just use `group(n)`. And you are always welcome

Comment: @tucuxi that's a different way to get those numbers, not by splitting, but by getting all the continuous digits

Comment: [And in case, you don’t want to wait until Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37482157/2711488)…

Comment: @Holger and you are here also... :)