# String regex Parsing with Semicolons in data

Tags: java, regex, string

How can I put together a regex to split a fiql string (example below) which separates conditions with a semicolon. The problem is semi colons can also be in the string.

I am using string split but can't find the right regex. I've tried below in which in trying to get the last semi colon before the ==:

```
query.split("(;)[^;]*==)
```

But it only works for the first key value.

Example string:

```
Key1==value1; key2==val;ue2;key3==value3
```

Target is array or list : `key1==value1, key2==val;ue2, key3==value3`
Problem here is the semicolon in value 2 is causing a split.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to split on `;` only if it has `==` after it, but also has no `;` between it and that `==`.

You ware almost there. Your code should look like

```
split(";(?=[^;]*==)")
```

notice that `(?=...)` part is [positive look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which simply checks if after `;` exists part which can be matched by subexpression `[^;]*==`, but doesn't include that part in final match so it won't disappear after splitting  (it is [zero-length](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html) match).

DEMO:

```
String str = "Key1==value1; key2==val;ue2;key3==value3";
for (String s : str.split(";(?=[^;]*==)")){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
Key1==value1
 key2==val;ue2
key3==value3
```

---

If you want to also get rid of space before `key2` then make it part of delimiter on which you want to split. So let regex match not only `;` but also whitespaces surrounding it. Zero or more whitespaces can be represented with `\s*` so your code can look like

```
split("\\s*;\\s*(?=[^;]*==)")
```

Comment: It's an at least quadratic regex, since you're reading the input string twice. If a string is long enough, or the file is big enough it would be really slow. It works, but should it be really used?

Comment: @bashnesnos True, this approach may not be best in terms of performance because of backtracking, but I am not sure if it will be O(N^2) (if that is what you mean that by *quadratic*). I suspect it will be closer to O(2*N). This regex will iterate to find `;`, then look-ahead will try to find match for `[^;]*==`, so `[^;]*` can iterate max to next `;`. So only area of characters which can be iterated more than once are those matched by `[^;]*`. But they still be iterated only max 2 times: once when we will search for delimiter `;`, and once in look-ahead.

Comment: Yes, I should've wrote 2*N. I followed the same logic as you, but how it transformed into quadratic in the end I dunno. Excuse me for confusion :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a group instead. And search tokens using `java.util.regex.Matcher` in a loop:

```
Pattern patrn = Pattern.compile("(?>(\\w+==[\\w;]+)(?:;\\s*|$))");
Matcher mtchr = patrn.matcher("Key1==value1; key2==val;ue2;key3==value3");


while(mtchr.find()) {
    System.out.println(mtchr.group(1));
}

Yields:
Key1==value1
key2==val;ue2
key3==value3
```

Adding ;? won't work unfortunately, since your middle tokens won't terminate anymore.

Comment: Nice one. But few hints: (1) String literals are placed inside `"..."`, not `'...'`, `'` is reserved to `char` type literals, (2) there is no point in wrapping *entire regex* in non-capturing group `(?:regex)`, you can simply use `regex`.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks, I've copy-pasted it from a groovy console :-) I've used non-capturing group to avoid back-tracking, but I agree that in current case it's more like a pre-caution.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW `\w` already contains `0-9` range, so you can skip `\d` in your regex. Also you are not obligated to add `EDIT: change description` in your answer. If you see that there is possible improvement or a problem simply correct it in your answer :)

Comment: @Pshemo yup, spotted the \d while correcting suggestion (2) :-) I've replaced global non-capturing group with a global atomic one, I guess it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

RegExp are evil.

if you can request to make minimal change on the string to be parsed, so value be surrounded by double qoutes, then, the string can be like `Key1=="value1"; key2=="val;ue2";key3=="value3"` then this post will help you
 check [Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

alternatively, you need to write a custom String parser. here is a quick non-optimized [CustomStringParser](https://gist.github.com/dwairi/0d0ea3022a18c2dcd3ee72c4e60ba6cb)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, it's not an attempt to parse arbitrary XHTML with regex here :-) Why not. If it's not that performance-critical regex should do the trick here.

Comment: absolutely, I agree. anyway, code snippet should be faster nevertheless :)