# Splitting a Scala String using comma, but free text also contains commas

Tags: java, regex, scala, text-parsing

I am writing parsing a JSON Strings and splitting them with a comma, but the Free also contains commas.I am unable to get my Pattern working for this. Tried various combinations but could not succeed.
        I am using this as part of the Spark streaming, I could not use the JSON parsers for the reason these data come randomly from 750+ random sources, so splitting and getting the text as key-value pairs was a reason to use splitting.

here is my String(Shortened for Stackoverflow use and readability).

```
            
{"Id":"1","Name":"Celtic,Manor Resort",**"Name":"Hotel Vila Gale Marina, Millennium Golf Course"**}
```

```
Code
=============
,(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*+\"){2})*+[^\"]*+$)
```

Can someone throw some help on this, please!

Comment: Can you reformat your question to be more readable?

Answer (score 0):

This answer appears to have a valid regex for parsing JSON:

[Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

```
,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)
```