# Can't read csv file with quotes inside quotes

Tags: java, csv

i have the following csv file:

```
"Maria,"Emilia",Brown",Martinez,5,40
```

I want the following outcome:

- "Maria,"Emilia",Brown"
- Martinez
- 5
- 40

I use the following matcher:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+?)\"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=,|$)").matcher(line);
```

But instead i get the following result:

- "Maria,"
- ",Brown"
- Martinez
- 5

How the hell can i fix it. I tried everything, but i can't seem to find a good pattern.

Comment: May be a dupe?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes

Comment: Nah, my method don't have the same problem

Comment: The answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2120714/1551685 should get you started though.

Comment: Welcome to the world of CSV processing. There is no absolute answer because CSV formats vary. Also, regexes are notoriously finicky beasts and perhaps not always the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work :

```
(".*"),(.*),(.*),(.*)
```

Don't forget to escape double quotes in your java String.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work. The first capture group will match `"Maria,"`, and the overall expression doesn't match the input shown. So that's wrong. And you don't necessarily get embedded quotes, or the same number of them, or just in the first item. So that's wrong, too.