# Ignoring commas inside pipes(|) while splitting data from a csv in java

Tags: java, csv

I have a *csv* file and I want to get all the values split by comma but the values inside pipe(`|`) should not be split. Sample row:

```
145132825311563,400000,D,|2112163531049,1000N1020170421826600001     |,B
```

I need the output as:

```
145132825311563
400000
D
|2112163531049,1000N1020170421826600001     |
B
```

I have tried some approaches given in similar questions but none of them worked for pipe(`|`).

Comment: Are you writing your own CSV parser? (why?) Or if not, which CSV parser are you using? In Apache Commons CSV, `CSVFormat.withQuote('|')` should work.

Comment: I am trying with String.split() method.

Comment: OK, don't do that. `split()` isn't good enough once you past the simplest form of CSV. Use a CSV library.

Comment: This answer may help, just change quotes for pipes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes/2120714#2120714

Comment: This helped. Thanks much!