# Java: splitting by comma and ignoring commas in tag <p>

Tags: java, arrays, regex, split

I would like to split a string by comma, but commas inside `<p></p>` should be ignored.

For example if I have the below String

```
" Test1, test2, <p> test3, test4, test5, </p> , test6, test7"
```

I need the result to be :

```
Test1
Test2
<p> test3, test4, test5, </p>
test6 
test7
```

Using special character how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Can you elaborate question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your String with this regex `,(?![^<p>]*</p>)`:

```
String str = "Test1, test2, <p> test3, test4, test5, </p> , test6, test7";
String spl[] = str.split(",(?![^<p>]*</p>)");
```

**Output**

```
Test1
test2
<p> test3, test4, test5, </p>
test6
test7
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: I missed the splitting part :-)

Comment: `[^<p>]` looks fishy. This is "anything that's not '>', '<' or 'p'". Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Arkadiy i think there are no way how you can represent <p> except this way did you have any idea?

Comment: errm... `<p>`? Some sort of nested negative lookahead? I am not the one answering :)

Comment: Here is what I came up with: `String spl[] = input.split("\\s*,\\s*(<p>.*</p>)?\\s*");` . Of course, it does not address the issue of nested tags, or capital `<P>` or `<p/>`. Please do not parse HTML with regex.

Comment: @Arkadiy it show me a wrong output check this https://ideone.com/ucYSql

Comment: Sure, it shows empty line because `,<p.../>` is followed by another `,` , so it sees two separators next to each other. I'll leave fixing this as an exercise to teh reader.

Answer (score 0):

You can first split using "p>":
`String[] temp = input.split("p>");`

You will have three elements in temp in your example:

- "Test1, test2, <"
- "p> test3, test4, test5,

  "p> , test6, test7"

Now in all strings in temp, replace '<', 'p>' and '

- "Test1, test2,"
- "p> test3, test4, test5,"
- ", test6, test7"

Finally, split each line using ',' again.
Apart from some (easily removable) empty strings, it should work

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it's not the most optimal, sorry, but off the top of my head.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String x = " Test1, test2, <p> test3, test4, test5, </p> , test6, test7";
    String newX[];
    newX = x.split(",");
    String newString = "";
    int j = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < newX.length; i ++) {
        if(newX[i].contains("<p>")) {
            count ++;
            j=i;
            while(!newX[i].contains("</p>")) {
                newString = newString + "," + newX[i];
                newX[i] = "";
                i++;
            }
            newString = newString + "," + newX[i];
            newX[i] = "";
            newX[j] = newString;
            newX[j] = newX[j].replaceFirst(",", "");
        }
        else
            count++;
    }
    String output[] = new String[count];

    j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < newX.length; i++) {
        if(newX[i] != "" && j < count) {
            output[j] =  newX[i];
            System.out.println(output[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```