# Read a CSV file with , as delim and numeric data also contain , separator to create RDD in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a csv file with one of the columns containing value enclosed in double quotes. This column also has commas in it. How do I read this type of columns in CSV in Spark using Scala into an RDD. Column values enclosed in double quotes should be read as Integer type as they are values like Total assets, Total Debts.

example records from csv is

```
Jennifer,7/1/2000,0,,0,,151,11,8,"25,950,816","5,527,524",51,45,45,45,48,50,2,,
John,7/1/2003,0,,"200,000",0,151,25,8,"28,255,719","6,289,723",48,46,46,46,48,50,2,"4,766,127,272",169
```

Comment: I tried {val result = input.map(x => x.split(","))}. It is taking "25 as one column value and 950 as another column value from the first line. But couldn't get any more ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to read with `SQLContext` as a `csv` file as it has well tested  mechanisms and flexible `api`s to satisfy your needs

You can do

```
val dataframe =sqlContext.read.csv("path to your csv file")
```

Output would be

```
+-----------+--------+---+----+-------+----+---+---+---+----------+---------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------+----+
|        _c0|     _c1|_c2| _c3|    _c4| _c5|_c6|_c7|_c8|       _c9|     _c10|_c11|_c12|_c13|_c14|_c15|_c16|_c17|         _c18|_c19|
+-----------+--------+---+----+-------+----+---+---+---+----------+---------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------+----+
|   Jennifer|7/1/2000|  0|null|      0|null|151| 11|  8|25,950,816|5,527,524|  51|  45|  45|  45|  48|  50|   2|         null|null|
|Afghanistan|7/1/2003|  0|null|200,000|   0|151| 25|  8|28,255,719|6,289,723|  48|  46|  46|  46|  48|  50|   2|4,766,127,272| 169|
+-----------+--------+---+----+-------+----+---+---+---+----------+---------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------+----+
```

Now you can change the `header names`, `change the required columns to integers` and do a lot of things 
 
You can even change it to `rdd` 

**Edited**

If you prefer to read in `RDD` and stay in `RDD`, then 

Read the file with `sparkContext` as a `textFile`

```
 val rdd = sparkContext.textFile("/home/anahcolus/IdeaProjects/scalaTest/src/test/resources/test.csv")
```

Then split the lines with `,` by ignoring `,` in between `"`

```
rdd.map(line => line.split(",(?=([^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)", -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

@ibh this is not Spark or Scala specific stuff. In Spark you will read file the usual way

```
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("app_name").setMaster("local")
        val ctx  = new SparkContext(conf)
        val file = ctx.textFile("<your file>.csv")
        rdd.foreach{line =>
        // cleanup code as per regex below
        val tokens = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1)
        // side effect
        val myObject = new MyObject(tokens)
        mylist.add(myObject)
    }
```

See [this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes) also.