# Regular Expression groups ignoring comma inside parenthesis

Tags: regex, string, icu

I know that are plenty of regular expressions around here similar to what I am going to ask, but couldn't find one that actually helps me.
This one got close, but it uses Java split method, but I need to capture the values using only regular expressions:
[Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

So, what I need to do is, given the below input:
`string,string([a-zA-Z]{0,9}),integer`
I would like to capture 3 matches:
    `string`
    `string([a-zA-Z]{0,9})`
    `integer`

Note that inside the parenthesis we can have a regular expression, which means almost any chars, even comma.
I can't use split here, because I am not using Java, but an internal declarative programming that uses ICU regular expressions and has an API for capturing groups, but not a regex based split method. 
Any help would be appreciated. And I am really sorry if there exists other posts that could be duplicated as this one, but I have spent a few hours looking around, and even played with the post I mentioned, but couldn't get to a solution.
Thanks

**EDIT**
The input I provided is just an example, but other inputs are also possible.
 
Besides, after @sin comments, I have reviewed the input, and we can actually assume we'll have quotes inside the parenthesis, like that:
`string("[\w]{0,9}"),integer,string`

Comment: So since the tool you're using doesn't have a split method, you're looking for a regex that has the 3 matches `string`, `string([a-zA-Z]{0,9})`, and `integer`? Or would a regex that captures these strings in a certain group also work?

Comment: Since icu regex isn't able to describe nested parenthesis, there is no solution.

Comment: Given this raw regex `\([a-zA-Z]{0,9})\)` I don't see how parenthesis can be used as delimiters. Parsing `(\([a-zA-Z]{0,9})\))` becomes this `([a-zA-Z]{0,9}))` or parsing `(\\([a-zA-Z]{0,9})\\))` becomes `\\([a-zA-Z]{0,9})\\)`

Comment: So, parsing out the _whole_ regex comes before anything.