# Faster way to split string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a (ton of) `string`(s) like this:

`HKR,Drivers,SubClasses,,"wave,midi,mixer,aux"`

I'm basically looking to split it into multiple `strings` at the `,` character.

However, if the `,` character is inside `"` or inside `%`, it should be ignored.

In other words from the line above I'd expect the strings:

```
HKR
Drivers
SubClasses

"wave,midi,mixer,aux"
```

(with one empty string represented by the blank line above).

If the line was `HKR,Drivers,SubClasses,,%wave,midi,mixer,aux%` then basically the same as above, only of course the last string to be returned should be `%wave,midi,mixer,aux%`.

I have some working code, but it's *incredibly* slow to process all of the lines and I very much need to find a faster way to do this.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetValues(string line)
{
    var insideQuotes = false;
    var insidePercent = false;
    var startValueIndex = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
    {
        if (line[i] == '%' && !insideQuotes)
        {
            insidePercent = !insidePercent;
        }

        if (line[i] == '"')
        {
            insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
        }

        if (line[i] != ',' || insideQuotes || insidePercent)
        {
            continue;
        }

        yield return line.Substring(startValueIndex, i - startValueIndex);
        startValueIndex = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you read the question, I don't want to split it at *every* `,`.

Comment: Use `VisualBasic.TextFieldParser` and set [`HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.hasfieldsenclosedinquotes(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true`.

Comment: @cogumel0 He's talking about using a Regex in the Split

Comment: @Yahya I understand the question was initially marked as java by mistake and java might be different, but in .NET there's no `string.Split` that accepts a regex.

Comment: It looks like a CSV. Why not using a CSV library like [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper)?

Comment: @Yahya and if a regex is the way to go, then post a regex that works and I'll gladly accept it as a question. I'm sure there's a better way, there's no denying it, that's why I asked here.

Comment: How slow is "incredibly slow" exactly, and how would you suppose this could be sped up?

Comment: @aloisdg it's not a CSV, it's very different from a CSV unfortunately. Only looks like one in these examples.

Comment: @cogumel0 No YOU need to understand that *mistake* gave you many unsolicited advice!! For using Regex, you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes) question which is very much similar to what you want.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is working code that needs a review. Thus it should go to codereview.stackexchange.com. Aprt from this you should use a profiler to determine if this is really the performance-bottleneck within your code.

Comment: @Yahya forgot an *I* in my comment above.

Comment: @CodeCaster taking several seconds over a few thousand lines to process. I imagine that at the very minimum getting rid of the `string.Substring` call would make it faster. But hoping a regex can make it incredibly faster.

Comment: My guess is that a regex is going to make it incredibly slower, but why don't you try? Anyway it really doesn't look to me like this actually is the bottleneck of your code. The CPU can do this at lightning speed. Are you measuring the time to read the file from disk as well?

Comment: One way or another you'll need to be splitting the string up, and regex is likely to be *slower* not faster

Comment: @Jamiec with regex you can use capture groups though so you get the result directly on the `Matches`

Comment: @cogumel0 that isnt a magic wand which will magicaly make it faster!

Comment: Must tell you ive been trying to improve your code and I cannot get the average runtime of your method above 0ms (0.00765ms to be exact). Even for a much longer string than your given input. Are you *sure* this is your bottleneck? (This is why premature optimization is the work of the devil BTW!)

Comment: Oh you have a bug also - the last item is not returned - you need a `yield return line.Substring(startValueIndex, line.Length-startValueIndex);` after the loop.

Comment: I doubt that you can make a huge performance-improvement by modifying this few lines of code unless either your string has millions of lines. You should focus on your *actual* problems, not assuming there *might* be one without measuring if this is true (which is done by a profiler, or at least a `StopWatch`).

Comment: Ok, turns out everyone saying this wasn't the bottleneck was right. There was a rogue `Console.WriteLine` hidden in the caller...

Answer (score 1):

Use `VisualBasic.TextFieldParser` and set [`HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.hasfieldsenclosedinquotes(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true`.

I would use a method like this which processes all lines at once:

```
public static IEnumerable<string[]> GetValues(string allLines)
{
    using (var parser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(new StringReader(allLines)))
    {
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        parser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] nextLineFields = parser.ReadFields();
            yield return nextLineFields;
        }
    }
}
```

Your sample:

```
var allLinesFields = GetValues("HKR,Drivers,SubClasses,,\"wave, midi, mixer, aux\"");
foreach (string[] lineFields in allLinesFields)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lineFields));
```

It will be more efficient than `String.Split` and also supports other things which you might not even have thought of. You can also handle special exceptions if the format was invalid.

Comment: Not sure how well this will deal with the fields enclosed in `%` though

Comment: The question claims the code shown is too slow. This answer contains no evidence this approach is any faster.

Comment: @Jamiec: that will be a problem, haven't seen it yet :) So OP has no idea in what format his csv comes? However, he could use other csv parsers like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) which support it

Comment: @CodeCaster: i am not responsible for evidences, i just want to help. I know this is more efficient though

Answer (score 0):

I've just reordered some of your query statements to avoid string operations. This should be more efficient.

```
   private static IEnumerable<string> GetValues2(string line)
    {
        bool insideQuotes = false;
        bool insidePercent = false;
        int startValueIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!insideQuotes && line[i] == '%')
            {
                insidePercent = !insidePercent;
            }

            if (line[i] == '"')
            {
                insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
            }

            if (insideQuotes || insidePercent || line[i] != ',')
            {
                continue;
            }

            yield return line.Substring(startValueIndex, i - startValueIndex);
            startValueIndex = i + 1;
        }
    }
```