# How to split the string containing comma inside quotes in csv file

Tags: java, regex

I have string like the below :

```
"18","1st",0,"Beattie, Mr Thomson",36.0000,"Cherbourg","Winnipeg, MN","C-6","","","male"
```

I want to split the string using comma ,ignoring  the commas inside the quotes using the split function .

i tried this

> line.split("(?:(?:\"\w*\"|\d*)),(?:(?:\"\w*\"|\d*))")

Comment: What's your question? Surely it's not 'write the code for me'? Presumably you tried this yourself first, can you show your attempt above?

Comment: use string.split(",")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

Comment: This is some example: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Comment: the duplicate have the answer you can use `str.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*)")` it will gives you a correct result

Answer (score 0):

There are enough existing modules which allow to import CSV-Files. e.g. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/