# Line breaks in field treated as end of line while parsing csv file

Tags: java, spring

IN a csv file that I have a record that renders like this:

```
,"SKYY SPA MARTINI

 2 oz. SKYY Vodka
 Fresh cucumber
 Fresh mint
 Splash of simple syrup

 Muddle cucumber & mint with syrup.
 Add SKYY Vodka and shake with ice. 
 Strain into a chilled martini glass. 
 Garnish with a fresh mint sprig and cucumber slice.",
```

with each line ending with a LF carriage return.

I thought that this would be treated as a string and the carriage returns wouldn't be treated as new lines, but this isn't the case, and is breaking my script. Is there a way to have the reader only have line breaks parsed if they're not flanked by quotes? I'm currently using this as my code, couldn't find a setting for the tokenizer that would allow me to perform this action.

```
        // instantiate description line mapper
    DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    DefaultLineMapper<LCBOProduct> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

    // set description line mapper
    reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);

    return reader;
```

Comment: `Is there a way to have the reader only have line breaks parsed if they're not flanked by quotes?` - I believe the convention is to use a double quote around the entire text for that column. I don't see the double quotes in your posted example.  If your parser doesn't support this then maybe try CSVParser.

Comment: Parsing CSV has some "interesting" corner cases.  There is OpenCSV and Apache's CSVParser. Use one of these, they are well debugged.  Also, the data you show is NOT CSV.  At a minimum, if you have a multiline field it must be in quotes.  If now, how would you distinguish a delimiting comma from a comma in the data?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to add the quotes that do exist for strings in this file. Also when debugging, it does state the quotation character as "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by this [CSV regex post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes), I have written a quick-and-dirty method for doing this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "\"BEEP\",\"BOOP\",\"TWO SHOTS\rOF VODKA\"\r\"BOOP\",\"BEEP\",\"LEMON\rWEDGES\"";

    String quote = "\"";
    String splitter = "\r";
    String delimiter = ",";

    parse(line, delimiter, quote, splitter);
}

public static void parse(String data, String delimiter, String quote, String splitter) {
    String regex = splitter+"(?=(?:[^"+quote+"]*\"[^"+quote+"]*\")*[^"+quote+"]*$)";

    String[] lines = data.split(regex, -1);

    List<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    for(String line : lines) {
        records.add(line.split(delimiter, -1));
    }

    for(String[] line : records) {
        for(String record : line) {
            System.out.println("RECORD: " + record); //do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, considering the large size of some CSV files, you will need to chug along with a StringBuilder and likely use `myStringBuilder.toString().split(regex, -1);` for the `parse` method.

This is likely not the Spring way of doing things. But as Jim Garrison commented, this is an edge case that I'm not sure if Spring has ways of solving.

A more complex regex may be required if the records start using other nasty characters (commas, quotes, etc.). I don't know what the source of these records could be, but some sanitizing may be in order before splitting the file.