# Split with delimiter and ignore delimiter and quote character which is part of data

Tags: java, regex

I have data like below

> 111,222,"33,44,55",666,"77,88","99"

it is delimited by `,` and also placed between quote character to ignore delimiter inside data

```
String input = "111,222,\"33,44,55\",666,\"77,88\",\"99\"";     
String[] splits = input.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
  for(String s : splits){
        System.out.println(s);
   }
```

Above code is working fine and returns
`111`,`222`,`"33,44,55"`,`666`,`"77,88"`,`"99"`

but now the data itself contain quote character

> 111,222,"**33,"44,55**",666,"77,88","99"

I want to get back 
`111`,`222`,`"33,"44,55"`,`666`,`77,88`,`99` but I get `111,222,"33`,`"44,55"`,`666`,`"77,88"`,`"99"`

```
String input = "111,222,\"33,\"44,55\",666,\"77,88\",\"99\"";
```

the pattern is not working correctly
can someone help me to get the data if quote character is part of data

Comment: Have you looked at using a CSV parser for this? Like opencsv for example

Comment: You may consider a 2-step approach: 1) encode all `"` inside `"` after a `,` (or start of string) and `"` before a `,` (or end of string) as, say, `&quot;` and then 2) split using the current regex. See [this Java 9+ demo](http://ideone.com/aaYcbi).

Comment: I’d not use `split`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58013294/2711488)…