# Replacing all commas inside quotations marks (or the inverse)

Tags: regex, perl

Let's say I have the following sentence

```
Apples, "This, is, a test",409, James,46,90
```

I want to change the commas inside the quotation marks by `;`. Or, alternatively, the ones outside the quotation marks by the same character `;`. So far I thought of something like

```
perl -pe 's/(".*)\K,(?=.*")/;/g' <mystring>
```

However, this is only matching the last comma inside quotation marks because I am restarting the  regex engine with `\K`. I also tried some regex's to change the commas outside quotation marks but I can't get it to work.

Note that the spaces after commas outside the quotation marks are there on purpose, so that

```
perl -pe 's/,\s/;/g' <mystring>
```

is not a valid answer.

The desired output would be

```
Apples, "This; is; a test",409, James,46,90
```

Or alternatively

```
Apples; "This, is, a test";409; James;46;90
```

Any thoughts on how to approach this problem?

Comment: use `Text::CSV` for csv-data.  (Or any good version of it, like in Shawn's answer)

Comment: Here's a regex that matches commas only when outside quotes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1757107/256196

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use an actual CSV parser instead of trying to hack something up with regular expressions. The very useful [Text::AutoCSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::AutoCSV) module makes it easy to convert the comma field separators to semicolons in a one-liner:

```sh
$ echo 'Apples, "This, is, a test",409, James,46,90' |
    perl -MText::AutoCSV -e 'Text::AutoCSV->new(out_sep_char => ";")->write()'
Apples;"This, is, a test";409;James;46;90
```

For a non-perl solution, `csvformat` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is another handy tool, though it's harder to get the quoting the same:

```sh
$ echo 'Apples, "This, is, a test",409, James,46,90' |
    csvformat -S -U2 -D';'
"Apples";"This, is, a test";"409";"James";"46";"90"
```

Or (Self promotion alert!) my [`tawk`](https://github.com/shawnw/tawk) utility (Which also won't get the quotes the same):

```sh
$ echo 'Apples, "This, is, a test",409, James,46,90' |
    tawk -csv -quoteall 'line { set F(1) $F(1); print }' OFS=";"
"Apples";" This, is, a test";"409";" James";"46";"90"
```

Comment: (And by harder I mean it can't come close due to [a bug in csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/issues/938))