# How to read csv file with additional comma in quotes using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am having some troubles reading the following CSV data in `UTF-16`:

```txt
FullName, FullLabel, Type
TEST.slice, "Consideration":"Verde (Spar Verde, Fonte Verde)", Test,
```

As far as I understand, it should not be a problem for a reader, since there is a `quote` parameter to handle that.

```
df = spark.read.csv(file_path, header=True, encoding='UTF-16', quote = '"')
```

However, this would still give me an incorrect split:

[image]

Is there some way to handle those cases or do I need to work it around with RDD?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try quote like this : quote = '\"' . That is using escape character. Let us know if that works.

Comment: the quotes are supposed to enclose the whole column, not parts of the column

Comment: @vijayinani Unfortunately not :/

Comment: You will need some regex here. Some regex expert can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read as text using `spark.read.text` and split the values using some regex to split by comma but ignore the quotes (you can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)), then get the corresponding columns from the resulting array:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.read.text(file_path)

df = df.filter("value != 'FullName, FullLabel, Type'") \
    .withColumn(
    "value",
    F.split(F.col("value"), ',(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)')
).select(
    F.col("value")[0].alias("FullName"),
    F.col("value")[1].alias("FullLabel"),
    F.col("value")[2].alias("Type")
)

df.show(truncate=False)

#+----------+--------------------------------------------------+-----+
#|FullName  |FullLabel                                         |Type |
#+----------+--------------------------------------------------+-----+
#|TEST.slice| "Consideration":"Verde (Spar Verde, Fonte Verde)"| Test|
#+----------+--------------------------------------------------+-----+
```

**Update:**

For input file in `utf-16`, you can replace `spark.read.text` by loading the file as `binaryFiles` and then convert the resulting rdd into dataframe :

```
df = sc.binaryFiles(file_path) \
    .flatMap(lambda x: [[l] for l in x[1].decode("utf-16").split("\n")]) \
    .toDF(["value"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option as below (if you find it simple):

First read the text file as RDD and replace the `":"` with `~:~` and save the text file.

```
sc.textFile(file_path).map(lambda x: x.replace('":"','~:~')).saveAsTextFile(tempPath)
```

Next, read the temp path and replace `~:~` with `":"`again, but this time as a DF.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
spark.read.option('header','true').csv(tempPath).withColumn('FullLabel',F.regexp_replace(F.col('FullLabel'),'~:~','":"')).show(1, False)

+----------+-----------------------------------------------+----+
|FullName  |FullLabel                                      |Type|
+----------+-----------------------------------------------+----+
|TEST.slice|Consideration":"Verde (Spar Verde, Fonte Verde)|Test|
+----------+-----------------------------------------------+----+
```