# Regex split on comma that isn't preceded by a specific word

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have a CSV string that I want to split on commas, but only if the comma isn't preceded by a specific word *somewhere else before it in the string*.

Below is an example of the input.

```
1,2,3,Test Message,JSON={ "book": { "title": "Hello, there, world" } }
```

In the above case, any commas after the word 'JSON=' should not cause the string to split, so I would be hoping for the following split.

```
1
2
3
Test Message
JSON={ "book": { "title": "Hello, there, world" } }
```

Ideally, I'd like to use `Regex.Split` to split the string and I think I need to use a negative look behind, but I'm not sure of the syntax required to achieve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might easier to match the portion up the stop word, assuming the stop word portion is at the end and then split the front portion.

Comment: In the general case, CSV parsing requires stateful processing of quoted strings.  You can't just throw `Split()` at it, not even a regex-capable `Split()`.

Comment: Also note that while this data is valid CSV, it is not a valid CSV encoding of JSON.  Proper CSV parsing will consume the quotes leaving none in the output for the JSON parser to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below regex to parse JSON in CSV mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

C# code -

```
var csvContent = "1,2,3,Test Message,JSON={ \"book\": { \"title\": \"Hello, there, world\" } }";
var split = Regex.Split(csvContent, ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

JS demo -

```js
const csv = '1,2,3,Test Message,JSON={ "book": { "title": "Hello, there, world" } }';

console.log(csv.split(/,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)/));
```