# How can two CSV files with the same data but different column orders be validated in Java?

Tags: java, csv, java-11, file-comparison, csvreader

I am trying to compare two CSV files that have the same data but columns in different orders. When the column orders match, the following code works: How can I tweak my following code to make it work when column orders don't match between the CSV files?

```
        Set<String> source = new HashSet<>(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readLines(new File(sourceFile)));
        Set<String> target = new HashSet<>(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readLines(new File(targetFile)));
        return source.containsAll(target) && target.containsAll(source)
```

For example, the above test pass when the source file and target file are in this way:

source file:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

target file:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

However, the source file is same, but if the target file is in the following way, it doesn't work.

target file:

```
a,c,b
1,3,2
4,6,5
```

Comment: You're going to need to use some kind of CSV parsing library, such as [this one](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html)

Comment: In your example, are `a,b,c` and `a,c,b` column headers?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Yes.

Comment: What if the lines are in a different order? Suppose, for example, "target file" contained `a,b,c // 4,5,6 // 1, 2, 3` ? (`//` represents line separator).

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer That should work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Set` relies on properly functioning `.equals`method for comparison, whether detecting duplicates, or comparing it's elements to those in another `Collection`. When I saw this question, my first thought was to create a new `class` for Objects to put into your `Set` Objects, replacing the `String` Objects. But, at the time, it was easier and faster to produce the code in my previous answer.

Here is another solution, which is closer to my first thought. To start, I created a `Pair` class, which overrides `.hashCode ()` and `.equals (Object other)`.

```
package comparecsv1;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Pair <T, U> {
        
        private final T t;
        private final U u;
    
        Pair (T aT, U aU) {
            this.t = aT;
            this.u = aU;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 3;
            hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.t);
            hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.u);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {  return true;   }
            if (obj == null) {  return false;  }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {  return false;   }
            final Pair<?, ?> other = (Pair<?, ?>) obj;
            if (!Objects.equals(this.t, other.t)) {
                return false;
            }
            return Objects.equals(this.u, other.u);
        } // end equals
    } // end class pair
```

The `.equals (Object obj)` and the `.hashCode ()` methods were auto-generated by the IDE. As you know, `.hashCode()` should always be overridden when `.equals` is overridden. Also, some `Collection` Objects, such as `HashMap` and `HashSet` rely on proper `.hashCode()` methods.

After creating `class Pair<T,U>`, I created `class CompareCSV1`. The idea here is to use a `Set<Set<Pair<String, String>>>` where you have `Set<String>` in your code.

- A `Pair<String, String>` pairs a value from a column with the header for the column in which it appears.
- A `Set<Pair<String, String>>` represents one row.
- A `Set<Set<Pair<String, String>>>` represents all the rows.

  ```
  package comparecsv1;

  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.HashSet;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Set;


  public final class CompareCSV1 {

     private final Set<Set<Pair<String, String>>> theSet;
     private final String [] columnHeader;

     private CompareCSV1 (String columnHeadings, String headerSplitRegex) {
         columnHeader = columnHeadings.split (headerSplitRegex);
         theSet = new HashSet<> ();
     }

     private  Set<Pair<String, String>> createLine 
                  (String columnSource, String columnSplitRegex) {
         String [] column = columnSource.split (columnSplitRegex);
         Set<Pair<String, String>> lineSet = new HashSet<> ();
         int i = 0;     
         for (String columnValue: column) {
            lineSet.add (new Pair (columnValue, columnHeader [i++]));            
         }
         return lineSet;
     }

     public Set<Set<Pair<String, String>>> getSet () { return theSet; }
     public String [] getColumnHeaders ()  {
         return Arrays.copyOf (columnHeader, columnHeader.length);
     }

     public static CompareCSV1 createFromData (List<String> theData
             , String headerSplitRegex, String columnSplitRegex) {
         CompareCSV1 result = 
            new CompareCSV1 (theData.get(0), headerSplitRegex);
         for (int i = 1; i < theData.size(); ++i) {
             result.theSet.add(result.createLine(theData.get(i), columnSplitRegex));
         }
         return result;
     }


     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String [] sourceData = {"a,b,c,d,e", "6,7,8,9,10", "1,2,3,4,5"
             ,"11,12,13,14,15", "16,17,18,19,20"};
         String [] targetData = {"c,b,e,d,a", "3,2,5,4,1", "8,7,10,9,6"                
             ,"13,12,15,14,11", "18,17,20,19,16"};    
         List<String> source = Arrays.asList(sourceData);
         List<String> target = Arrays.asList (targetData);

         CompareCSV1 sourceCSV = createFromData (source, ",", ",");
         CompareCSV1 targetCSV = createFromData (target, ",", ",");

         System.out.println ("Source contains target? "
            + sourceCSV.getSet().containsAll (targetCSV.getSet())
            + ".  Target contains source? "
            + targetCSV.getSet().containsAll (sourceCSV.getSet())
            + ".  Are equal? " + targetCSV.getSet().equals (sourceCSV.getSet()));        

     } // end main     
   } //  end class CompareCSV1
  ```

This code has some things in common with the code in my first answer:

- Except for the column header lines, which must be first in the "source" and "Target" data, matching lines in one file can be in a different order in the other file.
- I used `String []` Objects, with calls to `Arrays.asList` method as substitutes for your data sources.
- It does not contain code to guard against errors, such as lines in the file having different numbers of columns from other lines, or no header line.

I hard coded `","` as the String split expression in `main`. But, the new methods allow the String split expression to be passed. It allows a separate String split expressions for the column header line and the data lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that could work. It relies on the first line of each file containing column headers.

It's a bit more than a tweak, though. It's an "old dog" approach.

The original code in the question has these lines:

```
Set<String> source = new HashSet<>(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readLines(new File(sourceFile)));
Set<String> target = new HashSet<>(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readLines(new File(targetFile)));
```

With this solution, the data coming  in needs more processing before it will be ready to be put into a `Set`. Those two lines get changed as follows:

```
List<String> source = (org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readLines(new File(sourceFile)));
List<String> target = (org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readLines(new File(targetFile)));
```

This approach will compare column headers in the target file and the source file. It will use that to build an `int []` that indicates the difference in column order.

After the order difference array is filled, the data in the file will be put into a pair of `Set<List<String>>`. Each `List<String>` will represent one line from the source and target data files. Each `String` in the `List` will be data from one column.

In the following code, `main` is the test driver. Only for my testing purposes, the data files have been replaced by a pair of `String []` and  reading the file with `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readLines` has been replaced with `Arrays.asList`.

```
package comparecsv;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class CompareCSV {

    private static int [] columnReorder;

    private static void headersOrder
                              (String sourceHeader, String targetHeader) {
            String [] columnHeader = sourceHeader.split (",");
            List<String> sourceColumn = Arrays.asList (columnHeader);
            columnReorder = new int [columnHeader.length];
            String [] targetColumn = targetHeader.split (",");
            for (int i = 0; i < targetColumn.length; ++i) {
                int j = sourceColumn.indexOf(targetColumn[i]);
                columnReorder [i] = j;
            }
    }

    private static Set<List<String>> toSet
                               (List<String> data, boolean reorder) {
        Set<List<String>> dataSet = new HashSet<> ();
        for (String s: data)  {
            String [] byColumn = s.split (",");
            if (reorder) {
                String [] reordered = new String [byColumn.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < byColumn.length; ++i) {
                   reordered[columnReorder[i]] = byColumn [i];
                }
                dataSet.add (Arrays.asList (reordered));
            } else {
                dataSet.add (Arrays.asList(byColumn));
            }
        }
        return dataSet;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] sourceData = {"a,b,c,d,e", "1,2,3,4,5", "6,7,8,9,10"
            ,"11,12,13,14,15", "16,17,18,19,20"};
        String [] targetData = {"c,b,e,d,a", "3,2,5,4,1", "8,7,10,9,6"
            ,"13,12,15,14,11", "18,17,20,19,16"};
        List<String> source = Arrays.asList(sourceData);
        List<String> target = Arrays.asList (targetData);

        headersOrder (source.get(0), target.get(0));
        Set<List<String>> sourceSet = toSet (source, false);
        Set<List<String>> targetSet = toSet (target, true);
        System.out.println ( sourceSet.containsAll (targetSet)
                + "  " + targetSet.containsAll (sourceSet) + "  " +
                   (    sourceSet.containsAll (targetSet)
                     &&  targetSet.containsAll (sourceSet)));
    }
}
```

Method`headersOrder` compares the headers, column  by column, and populates the `columnReorder` array. Method `toSet` creates the `Set<List<String>>`, either reordering the columns or not, according to the value of the `boolean` argument.

For the sake of simplification, this assumes lines are easily split using comma. Data such as `dog, "Reginald, III", 3`  will cause failure.

In testing this, I found lines in the file can be matched with their counterpart in the other file, regardless of order of the lines. Here is an example:

```
Source:
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9

Target:
a,b,c
4,5,6
7,8,9
1,2,3
```

The result would be the contents match.

I believe this would match a result from the O/P question code. However, for this solution to work, the first line in each file *must* contain column headers.

Comment: As you mentioned, I was looking for handling something like this too: `dog, "Reginald, III", 3`.

Comment: @ychaulagain That can be fixed. The [`String.split (String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes a "regex" parameter. So, it's a matter of finding the right regex. You might be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes) and its answers.