# Regex URL Path from URL

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, url

I am having a little bit of regex trouble.

I am trying to get the path in this url `videoplay`.

```
http://video.google.co.uk:80/videoplay?docid=-7246927612831078230&hl=en#hello
```

If I use this regex `/.+` it matches `/video` as well.

I would need some kind of anti / negative match to not include `//`

Comment: When I have to use regexes on urls fast and dirty, I usually include // at the beginning, before the capture group.   Note you can't do http://, because they might be accessing it using a different protocol, or even ://, because they might specify the port number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting parts of a URL (Regex)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This expression gets everything after `videoplay`, aka the url path.

```
/\/(videoplay.+)/
```

This expression gets everything after the port. Also consisting of the path.

```
/\:\d./(.+)/
```

However If using `Node.js` I recommend the native `url` module.

```
var url = require('url')
var youtubeUrl = "http://video.google.co.uk:80/videoplay?docid=-7246927612831078230&hl=en#hello"
url.parse(youtubeUrl)
```

Which does all of the regex work for you.

```
{
  protocol: 'http:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'video.google.co.uk:80',
  port: '80',
  hostname: 'video.google.co.uk',
  hash: '#hello',
  search: '?docid=-7246927612831078230&hl=en',
  query: 'docid=-7246927612831078230&hl=en',
  pathname: '/videoplay',
  path: '/videoplay?docid=-7246927612831078230&hl=en',
  href: 'http://video.google.co.uk:80/videoplay?docid=-7246927612831078230&hl=en#hello' 
}
```

Comment: The `url` node module is in legacy mode. The docs recommend using the `URL` class instead. See here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/url.html#url_legacy_url_api

Answer (score 45):

In case if you need this for your JavaScript web-app: the best answer I ever found on this topic is [here](https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561). Basic (and also original) version of the code looks like this:

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
```

Thank you John Long, you made by day!

Answer (score 17):

`(http[s]?:\/\/)?([^\/\s]+\/)(.*)` group 3

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/vK4rV7/1

Comment: It wouldn't work if there for a path such as `www.abc.com?param=xyz`. I slightly modified it like this to make it work (I also use non-matching group for the first two groups). `(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^?\/\s]+[?\/])(.*)`
Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eNUBb9

Answer (score 5):

```js
function getPath(url, defaults){
    var reUrlPath = /(?:\w+:)?\/\/[^\/]+([^?#]+)/;
    var urlParts = url.match(reUrlPath) || [url, defaults];
    return urlParts.pop();
}
alert( getPath('http://stackoverflow.com/q/123/regex-url', 'unknown') );
alert( getPath('https://stackoverflow.com/q/123/regex-url', 'unknown') );
alert( getPath('//stackoverflow.com/q/123/regex-url', 'unknown') );
alert( getPath('http://stackoverflow.com/q/123/regex-url?foo', 'unknown') );
alert( getPath('http://stackoverflow.com/q/123/regex-url#foo', 'unknown') );
alert( getPath('http://stackoverflow.com/q/123/regex-url/', 'unknown') );
alert( getPath('http://stackoverflow.com/q/123/regex-url/?foo', 'unknown') );
alert( getPath('http://stackoverflow.com/q/123/regex-url/#foo', 'unknown') );
alert( getPath('http://stackoverflow.com/', 'unknown') );
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
^(?:[^/]*(?:/(?:/[^/]*/?)?)?([^?]+)(?:\??.+)?)$
```

***([^?]+)* above is the capturing group which returns your path.**

Please note that this is not an all-URL regex. It just solves your problem of matching all the text between the first "/" occurring after "//" and the following "?" character.

If you need an all-matching regex, you can check this [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex) where they have discussed and dissected all possibilities of an URI into its constituent parts including your "path".
If you consider that an overkill AND if you know that your input URL will always follow a pattern of having your path between the first "/" and following "?", then the above regex should be sufficient.

Comment: Try this url: http://video.google.co.uk:80?docid=-7246927612831078230&hl=en#hello, this regex returns group1 = o

Answer (score 4):

for new Googlers,
use JavaScript web api URL at any environment:

```
new URL('your url string').pathname
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Comment: This is beautiful.

Comment: Regex URL Path from URL?

Comment: He is asking about Regex not existing functions

Answer (score 2):

Even though the answers using language features are good, here is one more way to split URL to components using REGEXP:

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
     ||            |  |          |       |   |        | |
     12 - scheme   |  |          |       |   |        | |
                   3  4 - authority, includes hostname/ip and port number.
                                 5 - path|   |        | |
                                         6   7 - query| |
                                                      8 9 - fragment
```

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on it extensively and here is the result:

```
(?i)(?<scheme>http|https|ftp|sftp|sip|sips|file):\/\/(?:(?<username>[^`!@#$^&*()+=,:;'"{}\|\[\]\s\/\\]+)(?::(?<password>[^`!@#$^&*()+=,:;'"{}\|\[\]\s\/\\]+))?@)?(?:(?<ipv4>((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?)))|\[(?<ipv6>(?i)(?:[\da-f]{0,4}:){1,7}(?:(?<ipv4_in_ipv6>(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?))|[\da-f]{0,4}))\]|(?:(?<sub_domain>[^\s~`!@#$%^&*()_+=,.?:;'"{}\|\[\]\/\\]+\.)*(?<domain>[^\s~`!@#$%^&*()_+=,.?:;'"{}\|\[\]\/\\]+)(?<tld>\.[^\s~`!@#$%^&*()\-_+=,.?:;'"{}\|\[\]\/\\0-9]{2,})))+(?<port>:\d+)?(?:\/(?<path>\/?[^\s`@#$^&=.?"{}\\]+\/)*(?<file>[^\s`@#$^&=?"{}\/\\]+)?(?<query>\?[^\s`#$^"{}\\]+)*(?<fragment>#[^\s`$^&=?"{}\/\\]+)?)?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R2d1aA/2) | [Git Repository](https://github.com/namnamir/threat-hunting/blob/main/training/regex.md)

So, in your case, there is just a need to get the group contains the path and add the word you like, i.e. `videoplay`. To be more specific, I am talking about this:

```
(?:\/videoplay(?<path>\/?[^\s`@#$^&=.?"{}\\]+\/)*(?<file>[^\s`@#$^&=?"{}\/\\]+)?(?<query>\?[^\s`#$^"{}\\]+)*(?<fragment>#[^\s`$^&=?"{}\/\\]+)?)?
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean a negative lookbehind? `(?<!/)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var subject =
'<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"><link rel="image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">';
var re=/\"[a-z]+:\/\/[^ ]+"/m;
document.write(subject.match(re));
```

You can try this

```
/\"[a-z]+:\/\/[^ ]+/
```

Usage

```
if (/\"[a-z]+:\/\/[^ ]+/m.test(subject)) {  // Successful match } else {    // Match attempt failed }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not a regex solution, but most languages have a URL library that will parse any URL into its constituent parts.  This may be a better solution for what you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
^http[s]?:\/\/(www\.)?(.*)?\/?(.)*
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you're after: `[^/]+$`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/rG8gB9

Comment: This doesn't match the path of a URL, just the very last part of the path.  With "http://google.com/foo/bar" it matches "bar"