# How to extract the DOI sub-string from a URL string? [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of urls of the following format:

```
https://doi.org/10.1145/2883851.2883900
```

I want to extract the values after "doi.org".Here in the example my expected output is:

```
10.1145/2883851
```

I could do it on single url but to apply how get the values from a list of URLs.

Comment: if its the same website: `extracted = [string.replace("https://doi.org/", "") for string in lst]`

Comment: for string i in lst I think you wanted, or am I wong?

Comment: yeah, sorry idk how i put in *in* twice

Comment: also possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023430/regex-url-path-from-url

Comment: If you could do it to a single URL, doing it for all URLs in a list is a simple matter of iterating over the list. It looks like you might find a python tutorial helpful. There are many good ones online. Here's a good one: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops

Comment: @Ironkey worked

Comment: great glad i could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of urls with the same domain name and want to return a list of values in 10.1145/2883851 format :

```py
def replace_url(urls):
    result = []
    for url in urls:
        result.append(url[16:]) # len of "https://doi.org/" is 16
    return result
```