# CSV to flat xml java program

Tags: java, xml, csv

I have this excel file "flat.csv" which has element data inside the file and would like to covert it into a flat xml file in java, would require some assistance on how to do that, being googling but could find a decent example. Any tips would help currently I'm just researching for information. Does necessary has to be code,just links to sites that I might not be aware of, for further knowledge on this topic

Comment: Try coding, Read the CSV file, store the data and then try writing the data in the excel file.

Answer (score 1):

You can read CSV with this tool : [JSefa](http://jsefa.sourceforge.net/quick-tutorial.html) and after, serialize your CSV in XML.

You can also use : 
[OpenCsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) for parsing CSV (small, simple, reliable and easy to use)

[Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to parse/serialize XML (very easy to use, and creating fully human readable xml).

Some examples are available in web sites or google.

A previous stack over flow topic to help you : [Java lib or app to convert CSV to XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123/converting-csv-file-to-xml-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DOM` api to convert csv file into xml file. [This](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/) example might help you to create XML file.