# Using OpenCSV to convert CSV file to XML using byte array in input

Tags: java, xml, parsing, converters, opencsv

I have a question:

I'm trying to convert my CSV file to XML file and I'm seeing the response of this post: [Java lib or app to convert CSV to XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123/java-lib-or-app-to-convert-csv-to-xml-file)

I see that I need use this OpenCSV library and in particular, I must use this code:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(startFile));
```

where `String startFile = "./startData.csv";`

Now, I don't get a String as startFile, but I have a **byte[]** because, for other question, I have convert my file in byte[]. How can I use this code with byte[]?

Are there alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since CSVReader's constructor takes a Reader as parameter, you can pretty much pass anything that's readable to it.

So in your case, you may try using a bytes stream reader, as in:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(yourByteArray)));
```