# lib or app to convert CSV to XML file?

Tags: java, xml, csv, sunone

Is there an existing application or library in Java which will allow me to convert a **CSV** data file to **XML** file?

The **XML** tags would be provided through possibly the first row containing column headings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java lib or app to convert CSV to XML file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123/java-lib-or-app-to-convert-csv-to-xml-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this might help: JSefa

You can read CSV file with this tool and serialize it to XML.