# How do I add an item to a String array of type List?

Tags: java, arrays, list, csv, opencsv

In my code, I am reading in a text file using CSVReader and putting all that into a String array of type list:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("addTest.txt"), ',');
List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
reader.close();
```

I'm now wanting to add an item to the list, however, when trying to do this via `myEntries.add("test" + "," + "test2")`, it does not accept it. My goal here is to add an item or items to a new line, then I will use CSVWriter to write it back to file.

How do I go about adding an item, or items to a string array of type list? I've looked around but this problem still has me stumped.

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding items to an array. Then just add the whole array to the list.

Comment: I recommend you to look also at ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123/java-lib-or-app-to-convert-csv-to-xml-file#53547 ) and ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The List takes a String array not a comma delimitered string. Can add as

```
myEntries.add (new String [] {"test", "test2"});
```